# tensorflow: saving and restoring session

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a suggestion from answers:
[Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-restore-a-previously-saved-model-python)

I have an object which wraps a `tensorflow` model in a `sklearn` style.

```
import tensorflow as tf
class tflasso():
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    def __init__(self,
                 learning_rate = 2e-2,
                 training_epochs = 5000,
                    display_step = 50,
                    BATCH_SIZE = 100,
                    ALPHA = 1e-5,
                    checkpoint_dir = "./",
             ):
        ...

    def _create_network(self):
       ...


    def _load_(self, sess, checkpoint_dir = None):
        if checkpoint_dir:
            self.checkpoint_dir = checkpoint_dir

        print("loading a session")
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(self.checkpoint_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            self.saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        else:
            raise Exception("no checkpoint found")
        return

    def fit(self, train_X, train_Y , load = True):
        self.X = train_X
        self.xlen = train_X.shape[1]
        # n_samples = y.shape[0]

        self._create_network()
        tot_loss = self._create_loss()
        optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer( self.learning_rate).minimize(tot_loss)

        # Initializing the variables
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        " training per se"
        getb = batchgen( self.BATCH_SIZE)

        yvar = train_Y.var()
        print(yvar)
        # Launch the graph
        NUM_CORES = 3  # Choose how many cores to use.
        sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_CORES,
                                                           intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_CORES)
        with tf.Session(config= sess_config) as sess:
            sess.run(init)
            if load:
                self._load_(sess)
            # Fit all training data
            for epoch in range( self.training_epochs):
                for (_x_, _y_) in getb(train_X, train_Y):
                    _y_ = np.reshape(_y_, [-1, 1])
                    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={ self.vars.xx: _x_, self.vars.yy: _y_})
                # Display logs per epoch step
                if (1+epoch) % self.display_step == 0:
                    cost = sess.run(tot_loss,
                            feed_dict={ self.vars.xx: train_X,
                                    self.vars.yy: np.reshape(train_Y, [-1, 1])})
                    rsq =  1 - cost / yvar
                    logstr = "Epoch: {:4d}\tcost = {:.4f}\tR^2 = {:.4f}".format((epoch+1), cost, rsq)
                    print(logstr )
                    self.saver.save(sess, self.checkpoint_dir + 'model.ckpt',
                       global_step= 1+ epoch)

            print("Optimization Finished!")
        return self
```

When I run:

```
tfl = tflasso()
tfl.fit( train_X, train_Y , load = False)
```

I get output:

```
Epoch:   50 cost = 38.4705  R^2 = -1.2036
    b1: 0.118122
Epoch:  100 cost = 26.4506  R^2 = -0.5151
    b1: 0.133597
Epoch:  150 cost = 22.4330  R^2 = -0.2850
    b1: 0.142261
Epoch:  200 cost = 20.0361  R^2 = -0.1477
    b1: 0.147998
```

However, when I try to recover the parameters (even without killing the object):
`tfl.fit( train_X, train_Y , load = True)`

I get strange results. First of all, the loaded value does not correspond the saved one.

```
loading a session
loaded b1: 0.1          <------- Loaded another value than saved
Epoch:   50 cost = 30.8483  R^2 = -0.7670
    b1: 0.137484
```

What is the right way to load, and probably first inspect the saved variables?

Comment: tensorflow documentation is devoid of pretty basic examples, you have to dig in the examples folders and make sense of it mostly on your own

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You should try to rework this class so that `self.create_network()` is called (i) only once, and (ii) before the `tf.train.Saver()` is constructed.

There are two subtle issues here, which are due to the code structure, and the default behavior of the [`tf.train.Saver` constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.__init__). When you construct a saver with no arguments (as in your code), it collects the current set of variables in your program, and adds ops to the graph for saving and restoring them. In your code, when you call `tflasso()`, it will construct a saver, and there will be no variables (because `create_network()` has not yet been called). As a result, the checkpoint should be empty.

The second issue is that—by default—the format of a saved checkpoint is a map from the [`name` property of a variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.name) to its current value. If you create two variables with the same name, they will be automatically "uniquified" by TensorFlow:

```
v = tf.Variable(..., name="weights")
assert v.name == "weights"
w = tf.Variable(..., name="weights")
assert v.name == "weights_1"  # The "_1" is added by TensorFlow.
```

The consequence of this is that, when you call `self.create_network()` in the second call to `tfl.fit()`, the variables will all have different names from the names that are stored in the checkpoint—or would have been if the saver had been constructed after the network. (You can avoid this behavior by passing a name-`Variable` dictionary to the saver constructor, but this is usually quite awkward.)

There are two main workarounds:

1. In each call to `tflasso.fit()`, create the whole model afresh, by defining a new `tf.Graph`, then in that graph building the network and creating a `tf.train.Saver`.
2. **RECOMMENDED** Create the network, then the `tf.train.Saver` in the `tflasso` constructor, and reuse this graph on each call to `tflasso.fit()`. Note that you might need to do some more work to reorganize things (in particular, I'm not sure what you do with `self.X` and `self.xlen`) but it should be possible to achieve this with [placeholders](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) and feeding.

Comment: thank you! The `xlen` is used within `self._create_network()` to set the input size of `X` (placeholder init: `self.vars.xx = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, self.xlen])`). From what you say, the preferred way is to pass `xlen` to the initializer.

Comment: Is there a way to reset uniquifier / clear old tf variables upon re-initialization of the object?

Comment: To do that you need to create a new `tf.Graph` and make it the default before you (i) create the network and (ii) make a `Saver`. If you wrap the body of `tflasso.fit()` in a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` block, and move the `Saver` construction inside that block, the names should be the same each time you call `fit()`.