# Tensorflow Different ways to Export and Run graph in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

For importing your trained network to the C++ you need to export your network to be able to do so. After searching a lot and finding almost no information about it, it was clarified that we should use [freeze_graph()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) to be able to do it.

Thanks to the new 0.7 version of Tensorflow, they added [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#export_meta_graph) of it.

After looking into documentations, I found that there are few similar methods, can you tell what is the difference between `freeze_graph()` and:
 `tf.train.export_meta_graph` as it has similar parameters, but it seems it can also be used for importing models to C++ (I just guess the difference is that for using the file output by this method you can only use `import_graph_def()` or it's something else?)

Also one question about how to use `write_graph()`:
In documentations the `graph_def` is given by `sess.graph_def` but in examples in `freeze_graph()` it is `sess.graph.as_graph_def()`. What is the difference between these two?

This question is related to [this issue.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/615)

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like a separate library called "Tensorflow Serving" offers this functionality: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic.html. I'd still like to figure out how to do this in plain Tensorflow though!

Answer (score 41):

Here's my solution utilizing the V2 checkpoints introduced in TF 0.12.

There's no need to convert all variables to constants or [freeze the graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/615#issuecomment-184784850).

Just for clarity, a V2 checkpoint looks like this in my directory `models`:

```
checkpoint  # some information on the name of the files in the checkpoint
my-model.data-00000-of-00001  # the saved weights
my-model.index  # probably definition of data layout in the previous file
my-model.meta  # protobuf of the graph (nodes and topology info)
```

**Python part (saving)**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables()).save(sess, 'models/my-model')
```

If you create the `Saver` with `tf.trainable_variables()`, you can save yourself some headache and storage space. But maybe some more complicated models need all data to be saved, then remove this argument to `Saver`, just make sure you're creating the `Saver` **after** your graph is created. It is also very wise to give all variables/layers unique names, otherwise you can run in [different problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526252/1076564).

**Python part (inference)**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('models/my-model.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('models/'))
    outputTensors = sess.run(outputOps, feed_dict=feedDict)
```

**C++ part (inference)**

Note that `checkpointPath` isn't a path to any of the existing files, just their common prefix. If you mistakenly put there path to the `.index` file, TF won't tell you that was wrong, but it will die during inference due to uninitialized variables.

```
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;

...
// set up your input paths
const string pathToGraph = "models/my-model.meta"
const string checkpointPath = "models/my-model";
...

auto session = NewSession(SessionOptions());
if (session == nullptr) {
    throw runtime_error("Could not create Tensorflow session.");
}

Status status;

// Read in the protobuf graph we exported
MetaGraphDef graph_def;
status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), pathToGraph, &graph_def);
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error("Error reading graph definition from " + pathToGraph + ": " + status.ToString());
}

// Add the graph to the session
status = session->Create(graph_def.graph_def());
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error("Error creating graph: " + status.ToString());
}

// Read weights from the saved checkpoint
Tensor checkpointPathTensor(DT_STRING, TensorShape());
checkpointPathTensor.scalar<std::string>()() = checkpointPath;
status = session->Run(
        {{ graph_def.saver_def().filename_tensor_name(), checkpointPathTensor },},
        {},
        {graph_def.saver_def().restore_op_name()},
        nullptr);
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error("Error loading checkpoint from " + checkpointPath + ": " + status.ToString());
}

// and run the inference to your liking
auto feedDict = ...
auto outputOps = ...
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputTensors;
status = session->Run(feedDict, outputOps, {}, &outputTensors);
```

Comment: Hi, @peci1, thanks for your work. Could you tell me how I can compile this c++ code? Should I use bazel? Could you show any simple example command?

Comment: @YWPKwon The example is not a complete or standalone piece of code. You should incorporate it in a way that's useful to you (e.g. enclosing it into a main method). Compilation can then be done either the standard way using bazel, or you can have a look at my "hack" how to (mis)use the Python pip's install to a get a C++ environment. It's located here: https://github.com/tradr-project/tensorflow_ros and uses the catkin build tool ( https://github.com/ros/catkin/ ).

Comment: @YWPKwon To build C++ code using TF, you can also use bazel as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide, or CMake as described here: https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc

Comment: @Floop your "build.sh" relies as well on bazel. 
I wrote several example how to run a mode in [C, C++, Python and Go here](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference/)

Comment: as this solution was written a long time ago and tensorflow has actually evolved, is there any modern way to do (only)prediction part with C++? If so, could you please share the links to docs or tutorials?

Answer (score 21):

For predicting (and every other operations) you can do something like this:

First of all in python you should **name** your variables or operation for the future use

```
self.init = tf.initialize_variables(tf.all_variables(), name="nInit")
```

After training, calculations of so.. when you have your variables assigned go through all of them and save as constants to your graph. (almost the same can be done with that freeze tool, but i usually do it by myself, check "name=nWeights" in py and cpp below)

```
def save(self, filename):
    for variable in tf.trainable_variables():
        tensor = tf.constant(variable.eval())
        tf.assign(variable, tensor, name="nWeights")

    tf.train.write_graph(self.sess.graph_def, 'graph/', 'my_graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

Now go c++ and load our graph and load variables from saved constants:

```
void load(std::string my_model) {
        auto load_graph_status =
                ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), my_model, &graph_def);

        auto session_status = session->Create(graph_def);

        std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> out;
        std::vector<string> vNames;

        int node_count = graph_def.node_size();
        for (int i = 0; i < node_count; i++) {
            auto n = graph_def.node(i);

            if (n.name().find("nWeights") != std::string::npos) {
                vNames.push_back(n.name());
            }
        }

        session->Run({}, vNames, {}, &out);
```

Now you have all of your neural net weights or other variables loaded.

Similarly, you can perform other operations (remember about names?); make input and output tensors of proper size, fill input tensor with data and run session like so:

```
auto operationStatus = session->Run(input, {"put_your_operation_here"}, {}, &out);
```

Comment: I already make the running code in C++,  in my question I'm asking about different ways and their difference? Btw, the way you proposed is almost trick but the correct way is to use `freeze_graph()` code to freeze the nodes.

Comment: To be honest I haven't had time to test freeze graph yet. When i was working on my project, there were no clear api or tools for doing this at all(

Comment: @Alex Joz I've tried your solution. However, I have variables, for instance the moving mean and variance of several batch normalizations, that are not trainable variables and should still be stored. So I replaced 'for variable in tf.trainable_variables():' wit 'for variable in tf.global_variables():'. The problem is that the resulting network in C++ always gives the same output on different samples. Any idea where that might come from or how to correct it ?

Comment: So, it definitely behaves differently from python code, isn't it? Are you sure? Also, I'd suggest you not to use this method, except study case.  Automated frozen graph export works well.

Comment: I found terrible result with this approach. Though I was able to successful to export and import with the help of this process. Can anyone suggest is this a wrong approach?? My matching result nowhere near to the original :(

Comment: It's not wrong, but it is very old. Please, check out some other modern ways to do this, you will save a lot time =)

Comment: Do this would be supported in windows? Tensorflow C api support only linux and mac. Do C++ api support windows?

Comment: any modern solution available?

Answer (score 0):

For **TensorFlow v2**, it's suggested to use `tensorflow::LoadSavedModel` which can take model (`SavedModel`) saved via Python API `mode.save()`. So you don't need to use `FreezeSavedModel` and `GrapeDef`.

Suppose that your TensorFlow model files are saved in `model/` directory:

```
#include <tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h>
#include <tensorflow/cc/saved_model/tag_constants.h>
#include <tensorflow/cc/tools/freeze_saved_model.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;

//namespace tf = tensorflow;

int main() {

    const std::string export_dir = "model/";

    SavedModelBundle model_bundle;
    SessionOptions session_options = SessionOptions();
    RunOptions run_options = RunOptions();
    Status status = LoadSavedModel(session_options, run_options, export_dir, {kSavedModelTagServe},
                                &model_bundle);

    if (status.ok()) {
        std::cout << "Session successfully loaded: " << status;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed: " << status;
    }
return 0;
}
```