# TensorFlow 0.12 Model Files

Tags: c++, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I train a model and save it using:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(session, './my_model_name')
```

Besides the *checkpoint* file, which simply contains pointers to the most recent checkpoints of the model, this creates the following 3 files in the current path:

1. *my_model_name.meta*
2. *my_model_name.index*
3. *my_model_name.data-00000-of-00001*

I wonder what each of these files contains.

I'd like to load this model in C++ and run the inference. The [label_image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image) example loads the model from a single **.bp** file using `ReadBinaryProto()`. I wonder how I can load it from these 3 files. What is the C++ equivalent of the following?

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_model_name.meta')
new_saver.restore(session, './my_model_name')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently struggling with this myself, I've found it's not very straightforward to do currently. The two most commonly cited tutorials on the subject are: 
https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f#.goxwm1e5j
and
https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183#.g1gak956i

The equivalent of

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_model_name.meta')
new_saver.restore(session, './my_model_name')
```

Is just

```
Status load_graph_status = LoadGraph(graph_path, &session);
```

Assuming you've "frozen the graph" (Used a script with combines the graph file with the checkpoint values).
Also, see the discussion here: [Tensorflow Different ways to Export and Run graph in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508866/tensorflow-different-ways-to-export-and-run-graph-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, @Ian. I also found this: 
https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc#.ay0m5hj9k

Comment: Good find. It seems that they do what we are trying to do, but only with Python and not C++. I'm currently looking through this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/615 Which spawned this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508866/tensorflow-different-ways-to-export-and-run-graph-in-c

Comment: Have you guys finally succeeded ? I'm also struggling with that, I tried a lot of different methods, but most of them fail to save the variable values, the others crash or give me a constant output in c++ ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515671/tensorflow-freeze-graph-does-not-store-the-variable-values

Comment: I did eventually. I'll try to post an answer for you when I get a chance, unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: @IanConway sorry, I was faster :) I just wonder if you converged to the same point =)

Answer (score 6):

What your saver creates is called "Checkpoint V2" and was introduced in TF 0.12.

I got it working quite nicely (though the docs on the C++ part are horrible, so it took me a day to solve). Some people suggest [converting all variables to constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35663177/1076564) or [freezing the graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/615#issuecomment-184784850), but none of these is actually needed.

**Python part (saving)**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables()).save(sess, 'models/my-model')
```

If you create the `Saver` with `tf.trainable_variables()`, you can save yourself some headache and storage space. But maybe some more complicated models need all data to be saved, then remove this argument to `Saver`, just make sure you're creating the `Saver` **after** your graph is created. It is also very wise to give all variables/layers unique names, otherwise you can run in different problems.

**C++ part (inference)**

Note that `checkpointPath` isn't a path to any of the existing files, just their common prefix. If you mistakenly put there path to the `.index` file, TF won't tell you that was wrong, but it will die during inference due to uninitialized variables.

```
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;

...
// set up your input paths
const string pathToGraph = "models/my-model.meta"
const string checkpointPath = "models/my-model";
...

auto session = NewSession(SessionOptions());
if (session == nullptr) {
    throw runtime_error("Could not create Tensorflow session.");
}

Status status;

// Read in the protobuf graph we exported
MetaGraphDef graph_def;
status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), pathToGraph, &graph_def);
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error("Error reading graph definition from " + pathToGraph + ": " + status.ToString());
}

// Add the graph to the session
status = session->Create(graph_def.graph_def());
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error("Error creating graph: " + status.ToString());
}

// Read weights from the saved checkpoint
Tensor checkpointPathTensor(DT_STRING, TensorShape());
checkpointPathTensor.scalar<std::string>()() = checkpointPath;
status = session->Run(
        {{ graph_def.saver_def().filename_tensor_name(), checkpointPathTensor },},
        {},
        {graph_def.saver_def().restore_op_name()},
        nullptr);
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error("Error loading checkpoint from " + checkpointPath + ": " + status.ToString());
}

// and run the inference to your liking
auto feedDict = ...
auto outputOps = ...
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputTensors;
status = session->Run(feedDict, outputOps, {}, &outputTensors);
```

For completeness, here's the Python equivalent:

**Inference in Python**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('models/my-model.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('models/'))
    outputTensors = sess.run(outputOps, feed_dict=feedDict)
```