# How to load checkpoint and inference with C++ for tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-serving

I have Tensorflow with python api and got these checkpoint model file:

```
model.ckpt-17763.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-17763.index
model.ckpt-17763.meta
```

But I want a C/C++ shared library (.so file) when integrating into production. So I need to load these model file and inference with C++ code and compile to a shared library. Is there some tutorial or sample for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write c++ code to load and use your graph with the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639305/7456923).

You can use the files [here](https://github.com/cjweeks/tensorflow-cmake) to make a Cmake project with tensorflow outside the TF repository, and compile your library.

However, you'll still need the .ckpt files next to your .so, I don't know how to intergate them inside it.

There are a lot of questions about that on S.O., and a few tutorials (see the two cited in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992346/tensorflow-0-12-model-files/42103559#42103559)) but since tensorflow is evolving fast, they quickly become outdated, and it's always a bit of struggle to get it to work properly (totally feasible, and getting easier, though).