# Loading a trained model from Python to C++ in Tensorflow 1.2

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I'm looking to run a basic fully-connected neural network for the MNIST dataset with the C++ API v1.2 from Tensorflow. I have trained the model and exported it using `tf.train.Saver()` in Python. This gave me a checkpoint file, a data file, an index file and a meta file.

I know that the data file contains the saved variables while the meta file contains the graph from using Tensorboard on a previous project.

> However, I am not sure what is the recommended way to load those files
>   and run the trained model in a C++ environment in v1.2, since all the
>   tutorials and questions I've found are for older versions which differ
>   substantially.

I've found that `tensorflow::ops::Restore` should be the method to do such a thing, but I know that inference in Tensorflow isn't well supported, as such I am not certain what parameters should I give it in order to receive the trained model that I can just put into a `session->Run()` and receive an accuracy statement when fed test data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow Different ways to Export and Run graph in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508866/tensorflow-different-ways-to-export-and-run-graph-in-c)

Comment: Have a look in particular at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639305/1735003

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, however, as I've stated in my question, I'm using v1.2 which differs greatly in how sessions are run and many old methods are now unavailable/only for internal use in the code/deprecated.

Comment: I am using 1.2.1 and I still find the above post relevant. Which part of the C++ code is broken for you?

Comment: As far as I can see, ClientSession is the only provided way to run sessions and it only has one method, Run(). I don't see a way to access the Session class so I can use Create() or other methods.

Comment: In the answer I linked above, they call `NewSession` which returns a `Session*`.

Comment: I've found the problem. It seems that in my confusion with how bazel works, I forgot to add includes, now it's all good. Thank you!