# Running trained tensorflow model in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have trained an image classification network in python using tensorflow. The trained model was saved as a `.pb`. Now, I want to test the model, I need this to be done in C++.

I had used `numpy` in manipulating and handling data. During training phase the image is passed in as a numpy array. The image is stretched out as a 1D array and the class label is prepended to this array.

I'm confused as to how to pass the image data while running the model in C++, where `numpy` isn't available to me. I use `numpy` operations to manipulate and handle the data. In what format should I pass in the data if I have to execute it in C++.

Below is how I train and save my model

```
def trainModel(data):
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    X, y,keep_prob = modelInputs((741, 620, 1),4)
    logits = cnnModel(X,keep_prob)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y), name="cost")
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.0001, name='Adam').minimize(cost)
    prediction = tf.argmax(logits, 1, name="prediction")
    correct_pred = tf.equal(prediction, tf.argmax(y, 1), name="correct_pred")
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        batch_size = 30
        for e in range(11):
            batch_x, batch_y = data.next_batch(batch_size)
            batch_y = batch_y.astype('int32')
            x = np.reshape(batch_x, [batch_size, 741, 620, 1])
            labels = np.zeros(shape=(batch_size,4))
            labels[np.arange(len(labels)),batch_y]=1
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, y: labels,keep_prob:0.5})
            global_step.assign(e).eval()
        saver.save(sess, './my_test_model',global_step=global_step)
```

*741x620 is the size of the image

Comment: Tensorflow certainly makes it easy to build a network so complex you don't even know what you have. How exactly are you planning to run your NN from C++? Handrolled network or library? Note: library recommendations are off-topic here

Comment: @MSalters I,m planning to do it like [this](https://gist.github.com/jimfleming/4202e529042c401b17b7#file-loader-cc). 
I'm not sure if the solution may involve library recommendations. I'd like to call the model in C++, but I don't know how to pass the data around when I don't have access to numpy.

Comment: Ok, that's relevant. You plan to still use tensorflow. This leaves just the question how to insert inputs into tensorflow.

Comment: @MSalters Exactly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instructions for using a graph in C++ can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639305/7456923).

Here is some code to use your image as input:

```
tensorflow::Tensor keep_prob = tensorflow::Tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape());
keep_prob.scalar<float>()() = 1.0;

tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({1,height,width,depth}));
auto input_tensor_mapped = input_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();
const float * source_data = (float*) img.data;  // here img is an opencv image, but if it's just a float array this code is very easy to adapt
// copying the image data into the corresponding tensor
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    const float* source_row = source_data + (y * width * depth);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        const float* source_pixel = source_row + (x * depth);
        for (int c = 0; c < depth; ++c) {
            const float* source_value = source_pixel + c;
            input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, c) = *source_value;
        }
    }
}
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> finalOutput;

tensorflow::Status run_status = this->tf_session->Run({{InputName,input_tensor}, 
                                                       {dropoutPlaceHolderName, keep_prob}},
                                                      {OutputName},
                                                      {},
                                                      &finalOutput);
```

Comment: How do I print contents of the `finalOutput` when I'm evaluating the logits node(will be a tensor with 4 entries, there are 4 classes). I use `auto output_c = finalOutput[0].scalar<float>();
std::cout << output_c() << "\n";` this to print the output of prediction node, where output is just one number.

Comment: I have found this code online, can't remember xhan nor why we need to flatten, but it works for me:  
` tensorflow::TTypes<int>::Flat indices_flat = finalOutput[1].flat<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
     std::cout<<"outptut[i]:   "<<indices_flat(i)<<std::endl;
    }`

Answer (score 11):

You could use the C++ API as shown in the previous answer, nevertheless, compiling with the TensorFlow C++ API can be a headache. I recommend you using [cppflow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow) which a simple and easy to use wrapper to de C API. It allows you to feed data to the network as C++ vectors:

```
Model m("mymodel.pb");
m.restore("./my_test_model");

auto X = new Tensor(m, "X");
auto y = new Tensor(m, "y");
auto keep_prob = new Tensor(m, "keep_prob");
auto result = new Tensor(m, "prediction");

std::vector<float> xdata, ydata;
// Fill the vectors with data
X->set_data(xdata);
y->set_data(ydata);

m.run({X,y,keep_prob}, result);

std::vector<float> myresult = result->get_data<float>();
```

You can use this wrapper without installing full TensorFlow, you just need to download the .so of the C API.

Comment: Does this work with the ".meta" format produced by saver.save() instead of ".pb" format?