# Is there a C++ wrapper for the Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

We have trained our models and tested them successfully using the provided Python scripts. However, we now want to deploy it on our website and run a web-service for the second round of tests.

Is there a C++ wrapper so that we can use to run/execute our models the same way we do with Python scripts?

Comment: There is no specific api for object detection, but once you finish training, you can save model to `tf.GraphDef` or `tf.MetaGraphDef` format and then deploy it with tensorflow serving.

Comment: @Jie.ZHou: Thank you, but I I guess tensorflow serving can be used with google clouds only! I'm looking for something with the least dependency needs. bunch of dlls and libs so that I can use it easily anywhere. something like Caffe, which was very handy in such cases.

Comment: So basically you just want to use tensorflow with c++ ? In that case it's entirely possible of course ! You'll need to export your graph as explained in the object detection API, then run it in c++ like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031496/7456923) (in short)

Comment: @gdelab: yes thats exactly it. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find code to run object detection on C++ [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1741#issuecomment-325440393). You'll need an exported graph (.pb format), that you can get using [the TF object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md).

The compilation used to be tricky (except if you put your project in the tensorflow directory and compile everything with bazel, but you might not want to do that). I think it's supposed to be easier now, but I don't know how; or you can follow [these instructions](https://github.com/cjweeks/tensorflow-cmake) to compile tensorflow on its own and use it in a cmake project. You have another example of runing a graph in c++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031496/7456923).

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest way is to use [cppflow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow). It is a C++ wrapper for the TensorFlow C API. It is simple but really easy to use and you do not need to install it neither compiling with Bazel. You just have to download the C API and use it like this:

```cpp
Model model("graph.pb");
model.restore("path/to/checkpoint");

auto input = new Tensor(model, "input");
auto output = new Tensor(model, "output");

model.run(input, output);
```