# Libtorch works with g++, but fails with Intel compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, fortran, pytorch

I want to use a neural network developed in Python (PyTorch) in a Fortran program. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

What I am doing:

1. save it as torchscript: TurbNN.pt
2. call it from c++ program: call_ts.cpp, call_ts.h
3. call c++ program from Fortran program (using bind©): main.f90

I successfully compiled the codes using CMake (3.19.4) and g++ (7.5.0). However, I cannot compile them using Intel compilers (HPCKit 2021.1.0.2684):

```
# downloaded torchlib
export Torch_DIR=/home/aiskhak/nn/fortran_calls_torchscript3/build/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/

# set environment for Intel compilers
. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh

# cmake
cmake \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc \
-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=ifort ..

# make
make
```

After “cmake” everything looks fine (just like for g++):

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is Intel 20.2.1.20201112
-- The Fortran compiler identification is Intel 20.2.1.20201112
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/bin/intel64/icpc - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/bin/intel64/ifort - skipped
-- Checking whether /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/bin/intel64/ifort supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.1.1/linux/bin/intel64/ifort supports Fortran 90 - yes
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Torch: /home/aiskhak/nn/fortran_calls_torchscript3/build/libtorch/lib/libtorch.so  
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Success
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/aiskhak/nn/fortran_calls_torchscript3/build
```

However, after “make” I am getting:

```
Scanning dependencies of target call_ts_cpp
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/call_ts_cpp.dir/src/call_ts.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library lib/libcall_ts_cpp.so
[ 50%] Built target call_ts_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target fortran_calls_ts.x
[ 75%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/fortran_calls_ts.x.dir/src/main.f90.o
[100%] Linking Fortran executable bin/fortran_calls_ts.x
lib/libcall_ts_cpp.so: undefined reference to `c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
lib/libcall_ts_cpp.so: undefined reference to `torch::jit::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, c10::optional<c10::Device>, std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)'
lib/libcall_ts_cpp.so: undefined reference to `c10::DeviceTypeName[abi:cxx11](c10::DeviceType, bool)'
lib/libcall_ts_cpp.so: undefined reference to `torch::jit::Object::find_method(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
lib/libcall_ts_cpp.so: undefined reference to `torch::jit::Method::operator()(std::vector<c10::IValue, std::allocator<c10::IValue> >, std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, c10::IValue, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, c10::IValue> > > const&)'
CMakeFiles/fortran_calls_ts.x.dir/build.make:106: recipe for target 'bin/fortran_calls_ts.x' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/fortran_calls_ts.x] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:123: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/fortran_calls_ts.x.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fortran_calls_ts.x.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:148: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I am supposed to do with? I fixed similar problem when I had old g++, but my Intel compiler is new.

Below are my codes:

call_ts.cpp

```
#include "call_ts.h"
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// c++ function invariant_nn
//
// takes inputs, reads a neural network TurbNN.pt, do a forward pass
// and returns outputs
//
// inputs: 5 tensor invariants I[0:4] (float)
// outputs: 10 tensor basis coefficients G[0:9] (float)

void invariant_nn(float I[], float G[])
{
    // deserialize scriptmodule from a .pt file
    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    const char *arg;
    arg = "../src/TurbNN.pt";
    module = torch::jit::load(arg);

    // create inputs
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    float data[] = {I[0], I[1], I[2], I[3], I[4]};
    inputs.push_back(torch::from_blob(data, {1, 5}));
    //std::cout << "inputs\n" << inputs;
    //std::cout << "\n";

    // do forward pass and turn its output into a tensor
    at::Tensor outputs = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
    //std::cout << "outputs\n" << outputs;
    //std::cout << "\n";

    // return values
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        G[k] = outputs[0][k].item().to<float>();
        //std::cout << "G\n" << G[k];
    }

    return;
}
```

call_ts.h

```
#pragma once

/* export macros for library generated by CMake */
#ifndef CALL_TS_API
#include "call_ts_export.h"
#define CALL_TS_API CALL_TS_EXPORT
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

CALL_TS_API
void invariant_nn(float I[], float G[]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

main. f90

```
! fortran program main
!
! calls c++ function invariant_nn, which calls a torchscript with
! a neural network
!

program main

    ! define interface to interact with c++
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_float
    implicit none
    interface invariant_nn
        subroutine invariant_nn(I, G) bind (c)
            import :: c_float
            real(c_float) :: I(5)
            real(c_float) :: G(10)
        end subroutine
    end interface

    ! fortran program
    real(4) I(5), G(10)

    ! invariants
    I(1) = 1.01
    I(2) = 1.01
    I(3) = 1.01
    I(4) = 1.01
    I(5) = 1.01
    print *, "Tensor invariants ", I

    ! tensor basis coefficients
    call invariant_nn(I, G)    
    print *, "Tensor basis coefficients ", G

end program main
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
# stop configuration if cmake version is below 3.0
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)

# project name and enabled languages
project(fortran_calls_ts CXX Fortran)

# find libtorch
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

# if CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE undefined, set it to Release
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()

# compiler flags for release mode
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")

# set default build paths
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

# generated export header will be placed here
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

# c library
add_library(call_ts_cpp SHARED src/call_ts.cpp)

# fortran executable
add_executable(fortran_calls_ts.x src/main.f90)

# linked against c library
target_link_libraries(fortran_calls_ts.x call_ts_cpp)
target_link_libraries(call_ts_cpp "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

# we let cmake generate the export header
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(call_ts_cpp BASE_NAME call_ts)

install(TARGETS call_ts_cpp LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

install(FILES src/call_ts.h ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/call_ts_export.h DESTINATION include)

set_property(TARGET fortran_calls_ts.x PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

Comment: "I fixed similar problem when I had old g++" - what was the problem then, and how did you fix it?

Comment: The problem was: lib/libcall_ts_cpp.so: undefined reference to `c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
and so on (see after "make" command). For g++ it was fixed just by updating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you see `cxx11` in the linker errors?  It looks like your `libcall_ts_cpp` is compiled in a way that expects the new C++11 ABI for std::string but perhaps the library where those functions are implemented was compiled with the old ABI.  Here's a PyTorch forum post about the same problem: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/issues-linking-with-libtorch-c-11-abi/29510/11

The solution is to download a new copy of the PyTorch libraries built with the new C++11 ABI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am stupid. I tried to use the latest version of Torchlib and nightly version. However, I did not recognize that there are 2 versions available: Pre-cxx11 ABI and cxx11 ABI. I always downloaded the first one, but the second one worked for me!

Comment: @arsen if this solves your problem click on the checkmark and accept it

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks, done. Did not know that I should do it.