# How to load kernels/weights of each CNN layer (trained using Keras) into vectors (C++)?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

**Question:**
I want to load kernels/weights of each CNN layer into vectors such as `vector<vector<float>>`, used in C++ applications.

For example, given such a CNN structure (MNIST dataset), how to extract the kernels (`7*7*4`) in the first convolution layer into `vector<vector<vector<float>>>`?

```
Layer:                   Description:
Convolution              Input image 28*28, kernel size 7*7, stride size of 3, number of 
                         output channels 4
```

The CNN model is trained using Keras and saved in the files such as `mnistCNN.h5`.

Similar questions like [Running trained TensorFlow model in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027394/running-trained-tensorflow-model-in-c) only support loading the saved model and making predictions in C++. We cannot extract the parameters of each layer in their implementation.

So is there any example code for doing this?

Comment: Hi. There seem to be no ready to use C++ API that makes use of h5 Model Format. What you can do is make a preparation step in python, open h5 model and save it as Saved Model. Afterwards you can use the examples.

Comment: Hi,  @FedorPetrov , thanks for your advice! As you said, we currently cannot use C++ API to process `h5` file. I used an alternative method: read model from `h5` in python and then store the weights of each layer to the file (e.g., `.dat`), finally read these weights in C++.