# Restoring graph in tensorflow fails because there is no variable to save

Tags: python, tensorflow, restore

I know that there are countless questions on stack and github, etc. on how to restore a trained model in Tensorflow. I have read most of them ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-restore-a-previously-saved-model-python),[2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/616),[3](https://codedump.io/share/v7tNqYd2n5dH/1/tensorflow-how-to-restore-a-previously-saved-model-python)).

I have almost exactly the same problem as 3 however I would like if possible to solve it in a different fashion as my training and my test need to be in separate scripts called from the shell and I do not want to add the exact same lines I used to define the graph in the test script so I cannot use tensorflow FLAGS and the other answers based on reruning the graph by hand.

I also do not want to sess.run every variables and manually map them by hands as it was explained as my graph is quite big (Using import_graph_def with the arguments input_map).

So I run some graph and train it in a specific script. Like for instance (but without the training part)

```
#Script 1
import tensorflow as tf
import cPickle as pickle

x=tf.Variable(42)
saver=tf.train.Saver()
sess=tf.Session()
#Saving the graph
graph_def=sess.graph_def
with open('graph.pkl','wb') as output:
  pickle.dump(graph_def,output,HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


#Training the model
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
#Saving the variables
saver.save(sess,"pretrained_model.ckpt")
```

I now have both graph and variables saved so I should be able to run my test model from another script even if I have extra training nodes in my graph.

```
#Script 2
import tensorflow as tf
import cPickle as pickle

sess=tf.Session()
with open('graph.pkl','rb') as input:
  graph_def=pickle.load(input)


tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='persisted')
```

Then obviously I want to restore the variables using a saver but I encounter the same problem as 3 as there are no variables found to save to even create a saver. So I cannot write:

```
saver=tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess,"pretrained_model.ckpt")
```

Is there a way to bypass those limitations ? I thought by importing graph it would recover the uninitialized variables in every node but it seems not. Do I really need to rerun it a second time like most of the answers given ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of variables is saved in a `Collection` which is not saved in the `GraphDef`. `Saver` by default uses the list in `ops.GraphKeys.VARIABLES` collection (accessible through `tf.all_variables()`), and if you restored from `GraphDef` rather than using Python API to build your model, that collection is empty. You could specify the list of variables manually in `tf.train.Saver(var_list=['MyVariable1:0', 'MyVariable2:0',...])`.

Alternatively instead of `GraphDef` you could use `MetaGraphDef` which saves collections, there's a recently added [MetaGraphDef HowTo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/meta_graph/index.md)

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for !!! Sorry to ask yet another question about restoring models! However I think that could be useful for others also !

Comment: @Yaroslav, I have used `MetaGraphDef`, yet I got the same issue. Could you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762114/converting-a-pb-file-to-meta-in-tf-1-3

Comment: Link is dead, I guess it was probably [this](https://haosdent.gitbooks.io/tensorflow-document/content/how_tos/meta_graph/)?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge and my tests you can't simply pass names to `tf.train.Saver` object. It must be either list of variables o dictionary.

I would also like to read model from **graph_def** and then load variables using saver - however attempting it results only in error message: "Variable to save is not a variable"