# Tensorflow, missing checkpoint files. Does saver only allow for keeping 5 check points?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am working with tensorflow and have been training some models and saving them after each epoch using the  `tf.saver()` method. I am able to save and load models just fine and I am doing this in the usual way.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:
    initialiser = tf.random_normal_initializer(config.mean, config.std)

    with tf.variable_scope("model",reuse=None, initializer=initialiser):
        m = a2p(session, config, training=True)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()   
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_dir)
    if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    ...
    for i in range(epochs):
       runepoch()
       save_path = saver.save(session, '%s.ckpt'%i)
```

My code is set up to save a model for each epoch which should be labelled accordingly. However, I have noticed that after fifteen epochs of training I only have check point files for the last five epochs (10, 11, 12, 13,14). The documentation doesn't say anything about this so I am at a loss as to why it is happening.

Does the saver only allow for keeping five checkpoints or have I done something wrong?

Is there a way to make sure that all of the checkpoints are kept?

Comment: 5 is the default, you can customize it in Saver constructor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can choose how many checkpoints to save when you [create your `Saver` object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__) by setting the `max_to_keep` argument which defaults to 5.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=10000)
```

Comment: There is also the  "keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours" arg which I prefer in most cases.

Comment: I don't understand why there's a default in the first place, If I use `Saver` I am doing so to save something, why would I want to throw away something I explicitly want to save?

Comment: @gokul_uf The checkpoints can be quite large if your model has many parameters. I assume that the default has been chosen to avoid running out of storage space. It's a tradeoff between two evils I guess.

Comment: @Styrke Agreed that models can be quite large, but storage is cheap and plentiful. Whereas GPU memory and compute is neither cheap nor plentiful. I'm sure most people would prefer to wake up to HDD running low on free space v. panicking about where their data went.

Comment: @Styrke can you recover the lost checkpoints after training? Like the checkpoints saved earlier that is not saved anymore?

Answer (score 2):

setting `max_to_keep=None` actually makes the Saver keep all checkpoints.
For eg.,

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=None)
```