# Use .ckpt and .meta -files to make predictions with Inception in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I used the Inception-library *(Tensorflow/models/Inception-tutorial on github)*, 
feeding selfmade TFRecord-files to imagenet_train.py, and ended up with a 7Gb directory containing .ckpt and .meta files.

How do i use them to make actual predictions?(also evaluating, testing, **testing with actual .jpg files**, continue the training)

What would be the next steps?Are there dummy-friendly examples(tutorials)?

*[I know there´s a thread with a similar name, but it contains barely a question nor answers.]*

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variables/index.html#restoring-variables provides pretty much everything you should need.

The code there is:

```
# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Do some work with the model
  ...
```

So at the `...` part, you could load your .jpegs and feed them into the network with placeholders and feeddicts.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help.  This is more of a bare-bone's answer to get you started.

Comment: The "..." is actually that gives me the most headaches. Is there newbie-friendly example code, that works without prebuild data-sets?

Comment: Push. Help please. I keep on struggling with using my Checkpoint files, but really need them to finish my school-project.

Comment: Oh, sorry Michael.  Life got busy.  Graduation, new job, baby,  house hunting...I'll set some time aside tomorrow to help you out, probably around lunch.

Comment: Thank you very much. Congratulation, and all the best.

Comment: Anything new yet?

Comment: I'm really sorry Michael,  Life is so busy.  :(  I don't even have time to do my own experiments and that makes me sad.  It makes me feel worse that I don't have time to help out like I said.  The best I can do is send you to this one maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-restore-a-previously-saved-model-python/

Maybe copy down their files down, and add in a train flag, then add in a if train (do their stuff) else eval (do your stuff.)  It shouldn't be terrible to figure out (I hope.  :) )

Comment: Again, sorry about offering to help and then not being able to.  I do feel quite bad about that.