# Tensorflow: Convert constant tensor from pre-trained Vgg model to variable

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

My question is how can I convert a constant tensor loaded from a pre-trained Vgg16 model to a `tf.Variable` tensor? The motivation is that I need to compute the gradient of a specific loss with respect to the Conv4_3 layers' kernel, however, the kernel were seems set to a `tf.Constant` type and it is not accepted by `tf.Optimizer.compute_gradients` method.

```
F = vgg.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pretrained_vgg16/conv4_3/filter:0')
G = optimizer.compute_gradients(losses, var_list=[F])

# TypeError: Argument is not a tf.Variable: Tensor("pretrained_vgg16/conv4_3/filter:0", shape=(3, 3, 512, 512), dtype=float32)
```

What I have tried is to use `tf.assign` method to update the kernel to a variable type tensor with initial value set to be the original kernel, but it gives a `TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input`

```
F = tf.assign(F, tf.Variable(F, trainable=False))
```

So, how can I achieve that? Many thanks in advance!

**Update:** I download the pretrained model according to [Pretrained Vgg16 Tensorflow model](https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16) and then I loaded the model by:

```
with open('vgg16.tfmodel', mode='rb') as f:
    fileContent = f.read()

graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(fileContent)

# Map input tensor
inputs = tf.placeholder("float", [1, 224, 224, 3], name='inputs')
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={ "images": inputs }, name='pretrained_vgg16')

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

All the code above is defined in a class named `vgg`.

Comment: Could you please describe the way you load pre-trained model? Maybe post the code of conv4_3 would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, of course, and I have updated the post. However I actually did not implement the  conv4_3 layer,  it comes with the 'vgg16.tfmodel' file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you did not get variables from the pre-trained model could be explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763208/4093741). Briefly, `tf.import_graph_def` just restore the structure of a graph, without the variables.

A solution to this is to build the model yourself, with same variable name to the pre-trained model. Then load pre-trained model and assign every variable with specific parameter.

I recommend [this vgg model](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/post/vgg16/).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Da.