# TensorFlow: Is there a way to convert a frozen graph into a checkpoint model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Converting a checkpoint model into a frozen graph is possible (.ckpt file to .pb file). However, is there a reverse method of converting a pb file into a checkpoint file once again?

I'd imagine it requires a conversion of the constants back into a variable - is there a way to identify the correct constants as variables and restore them back into a checkpoint model?

Currently there is support for conversion of variables to constants here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants

but not the other way round.

A similar question has been raised here: [Tensorflow: Convert constant tensor from pre-trained Vgg model to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071584/tensorflow-convert-constant-tensor-from-pre-trained-vgg-model-to-variable)

But the solution relies on using a ckpt model to restore weight variables. Is there a way to restore weight variables from PB files instead of a checkpoint file? This could be useful for weight pruning.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried before asking? Since a saved model contains about as much information as a checkpoint, a conversion should be as simple as loading one and saving as the other.

Comment: Currently I've searched the documentation and the best I can find is only a conversion from variables to constants here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants, which I used to freeze the graph. I would have tried it out if there was an obvious method via the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a clear path to achieve this. Moreover, I'm concerned if the transition from variables to constants make it hard to identify which constants to reinstate to variables. Since you've mentioned it's simple, could you show a minimum example?

Comment: I've got the same question. This is important to know because if you convert a Theano Keras model into a Keras Tensorflow model, and then import the model into real Tensorflow, you can't use the freeze_graph function to produce a .bytes version of the model.

Answer (score 5):

There *is* a method for converting constants back to trainable variables in TensorFlow, via the Graph Editor. However, you will need to specify the nodes to convert, as I'm not sure if there is a way to automatically detect this in a robust manner.

Here are the steps:

#### Step 1: Load frozen graph

We load our `.pb` file into a graph object.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Load protobuf as graph, given filepath
def load_pb(path_to_pb):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path_to_pb, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph

tf_graph = load_pb('frozen_graph.pb')
```

#### Step 2: Find constants that need conversion

Here are 2 ways to list the names of nodes in your graph:

- Use [this script](https://gist.github.com/sunsided/88d24bf44068fe0fe5b88f09a1bee92a) to print them
- `print([n.name for n in tf_graph.as_graph_def().node])`

The nodes you'll want to convert are likely named something along the lines of "Const". To be sure, it is a good idea to load your graph in [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to see which tensors are storing the trainable weights. Oftentimes, it is safe to assume that all const nodes were once variables.

Once you have these nodes identified, let's store their names into a list:

```
to_convert = [...] # names of tensors to convert
```

#### Step 3: Convert constants to variables

Run this code to convert your specified constants. It essentially creates corresponding variables for each constant and uses GraphEditor to unhook the constants from the graph, and hook the variables on.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor as ge

const_var_name_pairs = []
with tf_graph.as_default() as g:

    for name in to_convert:
        tensor = g.get_tensor_by_name('{}:0'.format(name))
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tensor_as_numpy_array = sess.run(tensor)
        var_shape = tensor.get_shape()
        # Give each variable a name that doesn't already exist in the graph
        var_name = '{}_turned_var'.format(name)
        # Create TensorFlow variable initialized by values of original const.
        var = tf.get_variable(name=var_name, dtype='float32', shape=var_shape, \  
                      initializer=tf.constant_initializer(tensor_as_numpy_array))
        # We want to keep track of our variables names for later.
        const_var_name_pairs.append((name, var_name))

    # At this point, we added a bunch of tf.Variables to the graph, but they're
    # not connected to anything.

    # The magic: we use TF Graph Editor to swap the Constant nodes' outputs with
    # the outputs of our newly created Variables.

    for const_name, var_name in const_var_name_pairs:
        const_op = g.get_operation_by_name(const_name)
        var_reader_op = g.get_operation_by_name(var_name + '/read')
        ge.swap_outputs(ge.sgv(const_op), ge.sgv(var_reader_op))
```

#### Step 4: Save result as `.ckpt`

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        save_path = tf.train.Saver().save(sess, 'model.ckpt')
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

And viola! You should be done at this point :) I was able to get this working myself, and verified that the model weights are preserved--the only difference is that the graph is now trainable. Please let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Loved this hack, but when trying to find the corresponding TF2 (or TF>=1.15) package - the Graph_editor library is deprecated and could not find a replacement for it anywhere...  Has anyone encountered a replacement for ```swap_outputs```?

Answer (score 2):

> If you have the source code that built the network it can be done relatively easy because the name of the Convolutions/Fully connected didn't changed by the freeze graph method, so you can basically investigate the graph and match the constants operations to their variables matches and just load the variables with the constants value. -- by [Almog David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4514785/almog-david)

Thanks to @[Almog David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4514785/almog-david)'s excellent answer above; I was facing the exact same situation that

- I have `frozen_inference_graph.pb` but not checkpoints;
- I have the source code to produce `frozen_inference_graph.pb` but I don't know the parameters.

and below is the three steps to solve the dilemma.

**1. Get pairs of node names and values from `frozen_inference_graph.pb`**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util

def get_node_values(old_graph_path):
    old_graph = tf.Graph()
    with old_graph.as_default():
        old_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(old_graph_path, "rb") as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            old_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(old_graph_def, name='')

    old_sess = tf.Session(graph=old_graph)

    # get all the nodes from the graph def
    nodes = old_sess.graph.as_graph_def().node

    value_dict = {}
    for node in nodes:
        value = node.attr['value'].tensor
        try:
            # get name and value (numpy array) from tensor 
            value_dict[node.name] = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(value) 
        except:
            # some tensor doesn't have value; for example np.squeeze
            # just ignore it 
            pass
    return value_dict

value_dict = get_node_values("frozen_inference_graph.pb")
```

**2. Create new graph using existing code; tune the model parameters until all the nodes in new graph are present in the `value_dict`**

```
new_graph = tf.Graph()
with new_graph.as_default():
    tf.create_global_step()
    #existing code 
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...

    model_variables = tf.model_variables()
    unseen_variables = set(model_variable.name[:-2] for model_variable in model_variables) - set(value_dict.keys())
    print  ("\n".join(sorted(list(unseen_variables))))
```

**3.Assign values to variables and save to checkpoint (or save to graph)**

```
new_graph_path = "model.ckpt"
saver = tf.train.Saver(model_variables)

assign_ops = []
for variable in model_variables:
    print ("Assigning", variable.name[:-2])
    # variable names have ":0" but constant names doesn't have.
    value = value_dict[variable.name[:-2]]
    assign_ops.append(variable.assign(value))

sess =session.Session(graph = new_graph)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(assign_ops)
saver.save(sess, new_graph_path+"model.ckpt")
```

This is the only way I could think of to solve this problem. However, it still exists some drawbacks: if you reload the model checkpoints, you will find (along all useful variables) a lot of unwanted `assign` variables such as `Assign_700/value`. This is unavoidable and looks ugly. If you have better suggestions, feel free to comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code that built the network it can be done relatively easy because the name of the Convolutions/Fully connected didn't changed by the freeze graph method, so you can basically investigate the graph and match the constants operations to their variables matches and just load the variables with the constants value.

If you don't have the code that built the network it still can be done but it's not straight forward to do it.

You can for example search all the nodes in your graph and look for operations of type Constant then after you find all the operations of type Constant you can see if the operation is connected to Convolution/Fully connected, e.g... (Or you can just convert all the constants it depends on you).

After you find out which constants you wish to convert to variables you can add variable to the graph that holds the value of the constant and then use Tensorflow [graph editor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor) to rewire the connections (use [reroute_ts](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/graph_editor/reroute_ts) method) between the const operation to the variable.

After you did it you can save your graph and when you load it again you will have your variables (but be aware that the constants will still remain in your graph, but they can be optimized out, by [graph-transform](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md) tool for example)