# Tensorflow Loading Model with Saver v2

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I just updated my local installation of Tensorflow to 0.11rc2 and I got a message saying that I should add a parameter to my saver to make it save in version 2.  I updated this and now I cannot load models that were saved in this format.  When I run my model, it saves after every epoch.  When it saves, it used to save files called `translate.ckpt-3916` and `translate.ckpt-3916.meta`.  Now I get three files instead of two, named `translate.ckpt-3916.index`, `translate.ckpt-3916.meta`, and `translate.ckpt-3916.data-000000-of-000001`.

To load data, I use the following code:

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.train_dir)
    if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):
        print("Reading model parameters from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        model.saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    else:
        print("Created model with fresh parameters.")
        session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
return model
```

Where `model` is a model object that was already initialized with the standard hyperparameters of my program.  This works without issue with saver v1.  `ckpt.model_checkpoint_path` evaluates to the path to `translate.ckpt-3916` regardless of version, so if the checkpoint was saved with v2, no file is found.

The contents of the `checkpoint` file in that directory (when saved with either version) are:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "translate.ckpt-3916"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "translate.ckpt-3916"
```

Is there a new method to load data with saver v2?  Otherwise, how can I load my checkpoints?

EDIT:
Changing the line `if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):` to `if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:` like is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-restore-a-previously-saved-model-python?rq=1) seems to work a little further but then throws the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [84] rhs shape= [98]
 [[Node: save/Assign_54 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@NLC/Logistic/Linear/Bias"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](NLC/Logistic/Linear/Bias, save/RestoreV2_54)]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method I posted in my edit was actually the correct way to get this to work.  The error I got was because the data had changed between when I made the checkpoint and when I tried to load it.

Just to make it visible, loading from a V2 checkpoint in the code above was done by changing the line `if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):` to `if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:`