# How to view trained weights and biases (in human readable format) from a trained Tensorflow Model (.ckpt) file

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have trained a CNN and created a tensorflow model file (.ckpt).

I have to implement the forward propagation on a hardware using the trained model and for that I need the updated weights and biases (as I got after the training).

However, the .ckpt file has binary encoding.

How do I convert it to some human readable format so I can read the updated model parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sess.run](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client/session_management#Session.run) to evaluate whatever weight/bias in your model. The result is basically a numpy array, then use [numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Comment: But how do I load the model.cpkt file?

Comment: @SaadQureshi since there are already a bunch of answers for this question on SO, I suggest read them up, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-restore-a-previously-saved-model-python