# What is the difference between tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession and tf.train.Supervisor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm wondering what is the difference between these 2 tensorflow object when used to train a neural networks ?

Comment: Overlapping functionality, but `MonitoredTrainingSession` is newer/better, Supervisor is on the way to getting deprecated. For instance, `MonitoredTrainingSession` supports retries when your connection gets dropped, whereas Supervisor-based training will just throw exception.

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov. So I understand that MonitoredTrainingSession is the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supervisor is on the way to getting deprecated and new users are encouraged to use to tf.train.FooSession classes
(from [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6604#issuecomment-270950324))

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to use these new features especially how one can use hooks with foosession classes ?

Comment: Doesn't appear so, the only examples I found is in tests, and existing usages, ie https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/8567f3693ccd4ddb5430af9474cff46d7a480152

Comment: Here is a simple `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/42f507f51bd612a9d5dda01672d9460a68b4914f/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py#L107