# What is the "RIGHT" structure to save/restore a model in Tensorflow during training/val/test?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to write some codes in Tensoflow that can train a model, run validation during training, and finally report results on test data for the best model selected via validation data. I was wondering is the following structure the right way to do that? [considering variable scopes, parameter sharing, saving/restoring, ..]

MyModel.py

```
class MyModel(object):

  def build_model(self, reuse):
     with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse = reuse) as scope:
        self.v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", [1, 2]) 
     // rest of the codes

  def train(self, sess):
    self.build_model(False)
    s1 = tf.train.Saver()
    init_opt =tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_opt)
    // model training
    // ...
    s1.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")

  def val(self, sess):
    self.build_model(True)
    s2 = tf.train.Saver()
    // do the validation
    s2.save(sess, "/tmp/best_model.ckpt")

  def test(self, sess):
    self.build_model(False)
    s3 = tf.train.Saver()
    s3.restore(sess, "/tmp/model_best.ckpt")
    //rest of the codes ...
```

And I wrote the following functions in the **two** different files:

train.py:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        mtrain = MyModel()
        mval = MyModel()

        for iter_i in range(num_training_iters):
           mtrain.train(sess)
           mval.val(sess)
```

test.py

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
        mtest = MyModel()
        mtest.test(sess)
```

I looked at Tensorflow tutorials, but none of them have this structure.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks