# Tensorflow - Saving and restoring a model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model-python) in Stackoverflow that shows how one can save and restore a model.

My question is how can I do that within my code below, as I'm not sure how to integrate it with my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cifar_tools
import tensorflow as tf

data, labels = cifar_tools.read_data('C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Testing')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 150 * 150])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 64]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 64]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))

w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([38*38*64, 1024]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))

w_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, 2]))
b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))

def conv_layer(x,w,b):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x,w,strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
    conv_with_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv,b)
    conv_out = tf.nn.relu(conv_with_b)
    return conv_out

def maxpool_layer(conv,k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1,k,k,1], strides=[1,k,k,1], padding='SAME')

def model():
    x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 150, 150, 1])

    conv_out1 = conv_layer(x_reshaped, w1, b1)
    maxpool_out1 = maxpool_layer(conv_out1)
    norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(maxpool_out1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
    conv_out2 = conv_layer(norm1, w2, b2)
    norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv_out2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
    maxpool_out2 = maxpool_layer(norm2)

    maxpool_reshaped = tf.reshape(maxpool_out2, [-1, w3.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    local = tf.add(tf.matmul(maxpool_reshaped, w3), b3)
    local_out = tf.nn.relu(local)

    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(local_out, w_out), b_out)
    return out

model_op = model()

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(model_op, y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(model_op, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 2, on_value=1.,off_value=0.,axis=-1)
    onehot_vals = sess.run(onehot_labels)
    batch_size = 1
    for j in range(0, 5):
        print('EPOCH', j)
        for i in range(0, len(data), batch_size):
            batch_data = data[i:i+batch_size, :]
            batch_onehot_vals = onehot_vals[i:i+batch_size, :]
            _, accuracy_val = sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_data, y: batch_onehot_vals})
            print(i, accuracy_val)

        print('DONE WITH EPOCH')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code I have used in the past for restoring. This should be done after the session creation, but before running the model.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    print(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    i_stopped = int(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1])
else:
    print('No checkpoint file found!')
    i_stopped = 0
```

And for saving, every 1000 batches, or in your case you could save every epoch:

```
if i % 1000 == 0:
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir, 'model.ckpt')
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=i)
```

It should be fairly straightforward implementing this into your code. Remember you must define the checkpoint directory where the model will be saved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. When trying to run the code, I'm getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn.py", line 63, in <module>
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
NameError: name 'FLAGS' is not defined

Comment: Yes, the `FLAGS.checkpoint_dir` can be anything you'd like. I suggest explicitly defining your path, say: `ckpt_path = /path/to/ckpts/` where you would like your checkpoints to be stored and use `ckpt_path` in place of `FLAGS.checkpoint_dir` . Apart from that, everything else should be fine