# Tensorflow : What is the relationship between .ckpt file and .ckpt.meta and .ckpt.index , and .pb file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used `saver=tf.train.Saver()` to save the model that I trained, and I get three kinds of files named:

- .ckpt.meta
- .ckpt.index
- .ckpt.data

And a file called:

- checkpoint

What is the connection with the **.ckpt** file?

I saw someone saved model with only .ckpt file, I don't know how to make it. 
How can I save model as a .pb file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

- the .ckpt file is the old version output of `saver.save(sess)`, which is the equivalent of your `.ckpt-data` (see below)
- the "checkpoint" file is only here to tell some TF functions which is the latest checkpoint file.
- `.ckpt-meta` contains the metagraph, i.e. the structure of your computation graph, without the values of the variables (basically what you can see in tensorboard/graph).
- `.ckpt-data` contains the values for all the variables, without the structure. To restore a model in python, you'll usually use the meta and data files with (but you can also use the `.pb` file):

  ```
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(path_to_ckpt_meta)
  saver.restore(sess, path_to_ckpt_data)
  ```
- I don't know exactly for `.ckpt-index`, I guess it's some kind of index needed internally to map the two previous files correctly. Anyway it's not really necessary usually, you can restore a model with only `.ckpt-meta` and `.ckpt-data`.
- the `.pb` file can save your whole graph (meta + data). To load and use (but not train) a graph in c++ you'll usually use it, created with [`freeze_graph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py), which creates the `.pb` file from the meta and data. Be careful, (at least in previous TF versions and for some people) the py function provided by `freeze_graph` did not work properly, so you'd have to use the script version. Tensorflow also provides a `tf.train.Saver.to_proto()` method, but I don't know what it does exactly.

There are a lot of questions here about how to save and restore a graph. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103559/7456923) for instance, but be careful that the two cited tutorials, though really helpful, are far from perfect, and a lot of people still seem to  struggle to import a model in c++.

**EDIT**:
it looks like [you can also use the .ckpt files in c++ now,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639305/7456923) so I guess you don't necessarily need the .pb file any more.

Comment: Thank you very much . Now if I want to load .ckpt-meta and .ckpt-data files to identified a picture's class , do you know how to realize this ? or do you have something about this?

Comment: You can look at the question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43909969/7456923

The idea is to use `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(path_to_ckpt_meta)

saver.restore(sess, path_to_ckpt_data)` and then use a collection or variable name to get back a handle on your important input and output tensors, then run inference just like if you had not saved and loaded, with sthg like `sess.run([prediction_class],feed_dict={x_input: data})`