# Tensorflow 2: Get the number of trainable parameters in a Model from Model Garden (Zoo)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

After choosing and downloading a model from [TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), it can be loaded as followed:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.saved_model.load(f'./efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/saved_model/')
```

However, it looks like one cannot extract the number of **trainable variables** directly/indirectly from the `model` variable, according to this [investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547313/tf-objection-detection-zoo-models-dont-have-trainable-variables).

Nevertheless, *the model training can continue*, with new data, as this is a typical use-case of a pre-trained model. There must be a way to get the number of **trainable variables**. But I don't know how.

I tried:

```
tf.trainable_variables
# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'trainable_variables'
```

##### Environment:

- Tensorflow 2.7.0 (implying CUDA 11.2, cuDNN 8.1).
- Windows 10 x64
- Python 3.9.7
- NVIDIA GeForce MX150, Compute capability: 6.1

Comment: Hi! It should be model.trainable_variables() when you are trying to extract trainable variables from model. Thanks!

Comment: @Tensorflow Support: When I typed `model.trainable_variables()`, I got `AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'`.

Comment: Sorry ! It was model.trainable_variables with out open brackets. Attaching a thread for reference. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules .

Comment: @Tensorflow Support: I tried again with `model.trainable_variables`, but still got `AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()