# How to structure Tensorflow model code?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am having difficulty finding how to structure my Tensorflow model code. I would like to structure it in the form of a Class for ease for future reuse. Also, my current structure is messy and the tensorboard graph output have multiple "model" inside.

The following is what i have currently:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

from utils import Utils as utils

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

class Neural_Network:
    # Neural Network Setup
    num_of_epoch = 50

    n_nodes_hl1 = 500
    n_nodes_hl2 = 500
    n_nodes_hl3 = 500

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_of_classes = utils.get_num_of_classes()
        self.num_of_words = utils.get_num_of_words()

        # placeholders
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.num_of_words])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, self.num_of_classes])

        with tf.name_scope("model"):
            self.h1_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.x, self.n_nodes_hl1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h1")
            self.h2_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.h1_layer, self.n_nodes_hl2, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h2")
            self.h3_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.h2_layer, self.n_nodes_hl3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="h3")

            self.logits = tf.layers.dense(self.h3_layer, self.num_of_classes, name="output")

    def predict(self):
        return self.logits

    def make_prediction(self, query):
        result = None

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('saved_models/testing.meta')
            saver.restore(sess, 'saved_models/testing')

            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            prediction = self.predict()
            prediction = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={self.x : query})
            prediction = prediction.tolist()
            prediction = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)
            prediction = sess.run(prediction)
            print prediction

            return utils.get_label_from_encoding(prediction[0])

    def train(self, data):

        print len(data['values'])
        print len(data['labels'])

        prediction = self.predict()

        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=self.y))
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

            writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("mygraph/logs", tf.get_default_graph())

            for epoch in range(self.num_of_epoch):
                optimised, loss = sess.run([optimizer, cost],
                                           feed_dict={self.x: data['values'], self.y: data['labels']})

                if epoch % 1 == 0:
                    print("Completed Training Cycle: " + str(epoch) + " out of " + str(self.num_of_epoch))
                    print("Current Loss: " + str(loss))

                    saver = tf.train.Saver()
                    saver.save(sess, 'saved_models/testing')
                    print("Model saved")
```

What i have found online is that many use much lower level code such as **tf.Variables** and **tf.Constant** hence, they are much more able to split up their code. However, as I am relatively new to Tensorflow, I would like to use higher level code first.

Can anyone advise me on how to structure my code?

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/

Comment: @Nicolas Does the format support saving and restoring of models? Cause [https://gist.github.com/danijar/8663d3bbfd586bffecf6a0094cd116f2](https://gist.github.com/danijar/8663d3bbfd586bffecf6a0094cd116f2)seems to indicate that might not be possible to save and restore models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented, a short answer to your initial question would be to read [this](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/), but as you asked a follow-up question in your comments, I thought it needs a more complete answer.

---

> Can anyone advise me on how to structure my code?

Obviously, structuring your code is a matter of taste. But, to help you making your own taste, here is the main thing you need to keep in mind: there are 2 different layers in TensorFlow, don't confuse them.

- The first one is the `Graph` layer which holds all your TensorFlow nodes such as

  - `tensors` (e.g. `tf.placeholder`, `tf.constant`, `tf.Variables`, etc..), or
  - `operations` (`tf.add`, `tf.matmul`, etc..). The `Graph` contains your **model** *per se* and might contains much more such as: a loss function, an optimizer to train your model, an input data pipeline, etc.

Each of this nodes has a name you can use to retrieve it directly from the graph (e.g. using the `tf.get_variable` method or `tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name`).

- The second layer is the way you build your TensorFlow `Graph` using the Python (or the C++ or the Java, ...) API. This is likely this layer you had in mind when asking your question. But, in a way, this layer is really more a model factory rather than a model.

---

> Does the format support saving and restoring of models?

It depends on what you mean by *model* even if the answer is yes in both cases.

- If you had in mind the TensorFlow `Graph`, the answer is **yes**, you can save and restore your `Graph` because it doesn't depend on how you construct it. Just look at the *Saving and Restoring* section of this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) to get some insights on how to do it or look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43784657/4282745) where only the `Graph` is restored
- If you had in mind the Python class, the short answer is **no**. *But* you can make up something to make it a **yes**.
  As written in the previous item, TensorFlow checkpoint doesn't saved the Python (nor the C++ or Java) object, but only the graph. But the structure of your *model* as a Python class lives somewhere else: it lives in your code.

  So if you recreate an instance of your Python class, and if you make sure that all your TensorFlow nodes are recreated in the `Graph` (so you get an equivalent `Graph`), then, when you'll restore the TensorFlow `Graph` from the checkpoint, your model as a Python-instance-linked-to-a-TensorFlow-`Graph` will have been restored.

  See the *Restoring Variables* section of [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) for a trivial example where the Python-instances-linked-to-a-TensorFlow-`Graph` are actually Python variables (namely `v1` and `v2`) living somewhere in the module scope.

  ```
  # Create some variables.
  v1 = tf.Variable(..., name="v1")
  v2 = tf.Variable(..., name="v2")
  ...

  # Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  # Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
  # do some work with the model.
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")
    # Do some work with the model
    ...
  ```

---

I can only recommend to read (and upvote :)) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33759623/4282745) and its answers as you will learn a lot in terms of how saving/restoring work in TensorFlow.

---

Hopefully, it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: So does this mean that suppose I have a Network() class that defines the structure of the network. So to restore this model, all I have to do is to create an instance of Network() and proceed with using `tf.train.Saver().restore()` to restore the graph? No need for `tf.train.import_meta_graph()`, since creating an instance already defined the structure of the graph.

Comment: That is right. No need to reimport the structure of the graph as you'll have define it via the instance.