# tensorflow using restored (from saved )model get slower after some epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to save my model at the end of each epoch from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)

I did it in this way:

save:

```
model_dir = "{0}/epoch_{1}/res".format(train_dir, epoch_num)
saver.save(sess, model_dir, global_step=global_step_val)
```

restore:

```
 for ep_num in range(num_epochs):
        model_dir = "{0}/epoch_{1}/".format(train_dir, epoch_num)
        model_meta_file_name = [each for each in 
        os.listdir(model_dir) if each.endswith('.meta')][0]
        meta_path="{0}/{1}".format(model_dir, model_meta_file_name)
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir))
```

and continue evaluating my model with evaluation data.

but after 7-8 epochs,my evaluating process gets very slow, I think I 
   am saving some extra things, and after some epochs my graph is very 
   big. How do I solve this?

one point: gpu utilization is almost zero during this evaluation 
   process.I think fro some reason after some epochs,my process does 
   noyt run on GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)`

This line should only run once. You call it at every epoch, and that adds new ops to the graph, so the evaluation becomes slower.

Comment: @ Siyuan Ren
so,it s not necessary to save multiple meta graph ?one is enough