# CNN model with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, convolution, tensorboard

I am doing character recognition by building a Convolutional Neural Network model in Tensorflow. My model has 2 Conv layer followed by 2 fully connected layer. I have around 78K images from training and 13K images for testing. When I execute the model, I got accuracy around 92.xx% on test set. When I visualized my accuracy and loss curve on Tensorboard. I got a **vertical line**, but I did not know why I am getting this? I got curve like this [Accuracy and Cross Entropy curve when viewed on tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UouX6.png).

Also distribution curve of weights and biases shows a vertical line [Left side shows testing parameters (weights and bias) and right side shows training parameters on first conv layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGmow.png)

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. !!

```
def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):
with tf.name_scope(name):
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],padding="VALID")
act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
return tf.nn.max_pool(act, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")`

def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc"):
with tf.name_scope(name):
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")  # Truncated_normal
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
act = tf.matmul(input, w) + b
tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
return act

def model(use_two_conv, use_two_fc):
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1024], name="x")
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 32, 32, 1])
tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 3)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,46], name="labels")

if use_two_conv:
  conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 4, "conv1")
  conv_out = conv_layer(conv1,4,16,"conv2")    
else:
  conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 16, "conv1")
  conv_out = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")

flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 5 * 5 * 16])

if use_two_fc:
  fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 5 * 5 * 16, 200, "fc1")
  relu = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
  tf.summary.histogram("fc1/relu", relu)
  logits = fc_layer(fc1, 200, 46, "fc2")        

else:
  logits = fc_layer(flattened, 5*5*16, 46, "fc")
```

Comment: I've run into this exact problem tons of times, but it's hard to diagnose a code problem with no code! Would you post your training code?. You probably wrote ``writer.add_summary(current_summary)`` instead of ``writer.add_summary(current_summary, epoch)``. If you post the code, I'll happily post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @DylanF. It worked. But I have one more problem, On this trained model, I want to test a new image but how should I restore variables defined in functions conv_layer() and fc_layer() because there are variables like "conv1/W:0", "conv2/W:0". How should I use this trained model for a new image?

Comment: That's really a whole new question. Before you ask, though, you may want to reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model/47235448#47235448). I use [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235448/8217456) since it's the most up-to-date method. But the accepted answer is a valid solution too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've encountered this problem in the past, it's been a result of using

```
writer.add_summary(current_summary)
```

instead of

```
writer.add_summary(current_summary, epoch)
```

(using generic variable names because the relevant part of the asker's code isn't posted.) For instance,

```
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/Whatever/Path", sess.graph)
    for iteration in range(1001):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            _, current_summary = sess.run([training_op, summary_op])
            writer.add_summary(current_summary, iteration)
        else:
            _ = sess.run(training_op)
```