# Finish Tensorflow training in progress

Tags: algorithm, audio, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

> Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in
>   a different file format and you need to use a different restore
>   operator?

I'm currently training [Tensorflow-wavenet](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet/blob/master/README.md) with a directory of .wav audio files. Now, I want to stop the training and generate output, however the commands are not working. Here is terminal training:
[image]

I have seen [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model), but tf.train.export_meta_graph does nothing. Also, if I try to generate output in a new terminal tab, like so:

```
cd /Users/ruchirbaronia/Downloads/tensorflow-wavenet-master 
python generate.py --wav_out_path=generated.wav --samples 16000 logdir/train/2018-01-03T09-18-15/model.ckpt-0.index
```

I get this [error](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/60995691472150193fed0172e2e27b10) which basically says I can't generate output since training data has not been saved. How can I save and finish training?

Comment: Your screenshot shows you attempting to type a command into what looks like a running program which is not expecting or accepting input, let alone commands as input. Like you correctly concluded, you can open a new terminal window if you don't want to interrupt the running program to issue some other command. But so roughly the first half of your question is basically tangential and the answer to that part is "don't do that".

Answer (score 0):

`train.py` has an option for how often to save a checkpoint. For example,

```
train.py --checkpoint_every=10 ...
```

to save the checkpoint every 10 steps. By default, it is saved every 50 steps. Once you have a checkpoint, you should be able to use `generate.py`.