# how to import existing pretrained model in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

We have generated 4 files following this tutorial "https://github.com/sankit1/cv-tricks.com" checkpoint file, model-name.index, model-name.meta, model-name.data

Now we want to import these files in tensor flow object detection tutorial
"https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection"

how do we implement?

Comment: You need to use `tf.Saver.restore()`. See the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)