# How to make a copy of a trained model with tensorflow?

Tags: python, oop, tensorflow

I have a class with a model specification and some methods to train and evaluate the model. I want to make a copy of an object that was trained, I tried with `copy.deepcopy()` but did not work.

The code below  is just an example, but I want that works with any model using the same idea as below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys
import copy
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
FLAGS = None

class Model():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
        self.W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
        self.y = tf.matmul(self.x, self.W) + self.b
        self.y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
        self.cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.y_, logits=self.y))
        self.train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(self.cross_entropy)

    def train(self, mnist, sess):
        for _ in range(1000):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
            sess.run(self.train_step, feed_dict={self.x: batch_xs, self.y_: batch_ys})

    def test(self, mnist, sess):
        self.correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.y, 1), tf.argmax(self.y_, 1))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(self.correct_prediction, tf.float32))
        print(sess.run(self.accuracy, feed_dict={self.x: mnist.test.images, self.y_: mnist.test.labels}))

def main(_):
    # Import data
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
    m = Model()
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    m.train(mnist, sess)
    copy_of_m = copy.deepcopy(m)  # DOES NOT WORK !
    m.test(mnist, sess)
    copy_of_m.test(mnist, sess)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data', help='Directory for storing input data')
    FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Comment: Have you tried tf.identity(m)?

Comment: TensorFlow variables exist in a graph and can't be serialised/desrialised on their own. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model

Answer (score 3):

As explained by de1 in the comment

> TensorFlow variables exist in a graph and can't be serialised/desrialised on their own

You cannot simply copy a `tensorflow` model using `deepcopy` because the `Variable`s live inside a graph. Although the `Variable`s themselves cannot be copied (if you copy them you will receive this exception `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`), **you can copy their values by using `__getstate__/__setstate__`**. For example,

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

class Model():

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.normal = 2
        self.x = tf.ones([1,2])
        self.W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2]))
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
        self.y = tf.matmul(self.x, self.W) + self.b
        self.train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(self.y)
        self.inside_tf = ['W','b','x','y','train_step']
        
    def __getstate__(self):
        
        for item in self.inside_tf:
            setattr(self,'%s_val' % item,sess.run(getattr(self,item))) 
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        for item in self.inside_tf:
            del state[item]
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        
        self.__dict__.update(state)

# Import data
m = Model()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

copy_of_m = copy.deepcopy(m)
```

As you can see by running this script, before pickling (before copying), in the `__getstate__` method, we first save the values of the `Variable`s and then delete them from the copy of `self.__dict__`. Therefore, while pickling (copying), only the values of the `Variable`s will be pickled.

By running `[item for item in dir(copy_of_m) if item[:2] != '__']`, you can see the object `copy_of_m` has attributes `['W_val', 'b_val', 'inside_tf', 'normal', 'train_step_val', 'x_val', 'y_val']`. Although attributes like `W_val` are not `tensorflow` `Variable`s, but clearly, the values of the `Variable`s are the most important things to us.

Answer (score 2):

As in this thread [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14726) you can use `from copy import copy` and do `copy(model)` instead of deep copy.

You can also use `tf.keras.models.clone_model` and load the other model's weight in your copy model.