# tensorflow SavedModel - How to iterative save

Tags: tensorflow

I am adopting the new `SavedModel` API as I have learnt it is "the future" and should be preferred over `tf.train.Saver()`.

What I am trying to accomplish, is to save a model every `N` number of batches, and I want to keep a max of 20 saved models.
Obviously I can monitor this on my own, but if `tf.train.Saver()` could achieve this I believe there is a similar way to do so with `SavedModel`.
I would also like to have the option to explicitly save a model when I want to and to have them all named like `model-001`, `model-002` ....

This was all possible with `tf.train.Saver()` - I could define `max_to_keep` and `global_step` to save every epoch or so and I could save explicitly when I wanted to.

Is this achievable with the `SavedModel` API? If so how? An example would be appreciated.

It is reasonable to assume that the `signature def map` will be equal to all models.