# Restoring saved model

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, image-processing, tensorflow, mnist

I was trying to predict handwritten digits with tensorflow and mnist datasets. But I get error. How can I solve the error?

```
import tensorflow as tf
.
.    #code
.    #code
.    #code
.
y_pred= tf.nn.softmax(layer3)  # USING SOFTMAX

init_op= tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver= tf.train.Saver()

# RESTORING MODEL
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.restore(sess, 'model.ckpt')
    sess.run(init_op)

    prediction= tf.argmax(y_pred, 1)
    print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [imvalue],keep_prob: 1.0}
                       ,session=sess))
```

The code throws the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/monojit/writtenRecognition/digi.py", line 127, in <module>
sess.restore(sess, 'model.ckpt')
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'restore'
```

Comment: change to `saver.restore` more info can be found here https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)