# tensor flow namespace across classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, namespaces

A gist for the problem is available here: https://gist.github.com/sankhaMukherjee/97c212072385ee36ebd8bfab9a801794

Essentially, I am trying to generate a generalized class that can be used as boilerplate for my tensor flow projects. The gist provided is the most trivial example that I was able to come up with. I understand that this has to do with namespaces, but am not sure how I can resolve this problem.

I have a class `Test` with the following member functions:

1. `__init__(self, inpShape, outShape, layers, activations)`
2. `saveModel(self, sess)`
3. `restoreModel(self, sess, restorePoint)`
4. `fit(self, X, y, Niter=101, restorePoint=None)`
5. `predict(self, X, restorePoint=None)`

The functions themselves are trivial, and can be looked up within the gist provided. Now, given this class, we can try to test it to see how it does:

```
X = np.random.random((10000, 2))
y = (2*X[:, 0] + 3*X[:, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)

inpShape    = (None, 2)
outShape    = (None, 1)
layers      = [7, 1]
activations = [tf.sigmoid, None]

t = Test(inpShape, outShape, layers, activations)
t.fit(X, y, 10000)
yHat = t.predict(X, restorePoint=t.restorePoints[-1])

plt.plot(yHat, y, '.', label='original')
```

This is all fine!

Now we want to create another instance of the same class, and restore a model saved from here. It is here that all hell breaks loose. Lets update the above to incorporate that:

```
X = np.random.random((10000, 2))
y = (2*X[:, 0] + 3*X[:, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)

inpShape    = (None, 2)
outShape    = (None, 1)
layers      = [7, 1]
activations = [tf.sigmoid, None]

t = Test(inpShape, outShape, layers, activations)
t.fit(X, y, 10000)
yHat = t.predict(X, restorePoint=t.restorePoints[-1])

plt.plot(yHat, y, '.', label='original')

if True: # In the gist, turn this to True for seeing the problem
    t1 = Test(inpShape, outShape, layers, activations)
    yHat1 = t1.predict(X, restorePoint=t.restorePoints[-1])
    plt.plot(yHat1, y, '.', label='copied')
```

It turns out, we can no longer do this. It will totally mess up everything with a totally new graph alongside the old one. Is it now possible to create a new instance of the class that copies the old graph, and not create a totally new instance of the old graph?

Comment: Your model restore is not right, i have answered for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484676/restoring-model-take-to-long/50488160#50488160

Comment: Thanks Vijay! I'll try it

Comment: The TF namespacing isn't the same as python's you'll need to use some of the namespacing functionality.