# Re-train a deep learning by adding some more images to dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a model created by training with a dataset. Now I want to re-train the model by put some more images in that dataset with out deleting the already created model. I have some images which are slightly different from the images already exists in the dataset. The colour is the only different. So I want to train the model using these new images also. So how can I train the model again using new images without deleting the alredy trained data. I use Tensorflow in Python. How can I re-train the model?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from enum import Enum, unique


@unique
class InputType(Enum):
TENSOR = 1
BASE64_JPEG = 2


class OpenNsfwModel:
"""Tensorflow implementation of Yahoo's Open NSFW Model

Original implementation:
https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw

Weights have been converted using caffe-tensorflow:
https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow
"""

def __init__(self):
    self.weights = {}
    self.bn_epsilon = 1e-5  # Default used by Caffe

def build(self, weights_path="open_nsfw-weights.npy",
          input_type=InputType.TENSOR):

    self.weights = np.load(weights_path, encoding="latin1").item()
    self.input_tensor = None

    if input_type == InputType.TENSOR:
        self.input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    shape=[None, 224, 224, 3],
                                    name="input")
        self.input_tensor = self.input
    elif input_type == InputType.BASE64_JPEG:
        from image_utils import load_base64_tensor

        self.input = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None,), name="input")
        self.input_tensor = load_base64_tensor(self.input)
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid input type '{}'".format(input_type))

    x = self.input_tensor

    x = tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [3, 3], [3, 3], [0, 0]], 'CONSTANT')
    x = self.__conv2d("conv_1", x, filter_depth=64,
                      kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding='valid')

    x = self.__batch_norm("bn_1", x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')

    x = self.__conv_block(stage=0, block=0, inputs=x,
                          filter_depths=[32, 32, 128],
                          kernel_size=3, stride=1)

    x = self.__identity_block(stage=0, block=1, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[32, 32, 128], kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=0, block=2, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[32, 32, 128], kernel_size=3)

    x = self.__conv_block(stage=1, block=0, inputs=x,
                          filter_depths=[64, 64, 256],
                          kernel_size=3, stride=2)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=1, block=1, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[64, 64, 256], kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=1, block=2, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[64, 64, 256], kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=1, block=3, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[64, 64, 256], kernel_size=3)

    x = self.__conv_block(stage=2, block=0, inputs=x,
                          filter_depths=[128, 128, 512],
                          kernel_size=3, stride=2)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=2, block=1, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[128, 128, 512], kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=2, block=2, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[128, 128, 512], kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=2, block=3, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[128, 128, 512], kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=2, block=4, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[128, 128, 512], kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=2, block=5, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[128, 128, 512], kernel_size=3)

    x = self.__conv_block(stage=3, block=0, inputs=x,
                          filter_depths=[256, 256, 1024], kernel_size=3,
                          stride=2)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=3, block=1, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[256, 256, 1024],
                              kernel_size=3)
    x = self.__identity_block(stage=3, block=2, inputs=x,
                              filter_depths=[256, 256, 1024],
                              kernel_size=3)

    x = tf.layers.average_pooling2d(x, pool_size=7, strides=1,
                                    padding="valid", name="pool")

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, 1024))

    self.logits = self.__fully_connected(name="fc_nsfw",
                                         inputs=x, num_outputs=2)
    self.predictions = tf.nn.softmax(self.logits, name="predictions")

"""Get weights for layer with given name
"""
def __get_weights(self, layer_name, field_name):
    if not layer_name in self.weights:
        raise ValueError("No weights for layer named '{}' found"
                         .format(layer_name))

    w = self.weights[layer_name]
    if not field_name in w:
        raise (ValueError("No entry for field '{}' in layer named '{}'"
                          .format(field_name, layer_name)))

    return w[field_name]

"""Layer creation and weight initialization
"""
def __fully_connected(self, name, inputs, num_outputs):
    return tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=inputs, units=num_outputs, name=name,
        kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "weights"), dtype=tf.float32),
        bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "biases"), dtype=tf.float32))

def __conv2d(self, name, inputs, filter_depth, kernel_size, stride=1,
             padding="same", trainable=False):

    if padding.lower() == 'same' and kernel_size > 1:
        if kernel_size > 1:
            oh = inputs.get_shape().as_list()[1]
            h = inputs.get_shape().as_list()[1]

            p = int(math.floor(((oh - 1) * stride + kernel_size - h)//2))

            inputs = tf.pad(inputs,
                            [[0, 0], [p, p], [p, p], [0, 0]],
                            'CONSTANT')
        else:
            raise Exception('unsupported kernel size for padding: "{}"'
                            .format(kernel_size))

    return tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs, filter_depth,
        kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size),
        strides=(stride, stride), padding='valid',
        activation=None, trainable=trainable, name=name,
        kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "weights"), dtype=tf.float32),
        bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "biases"), dtype=tf.float32))

def __batch_norm(self, name, inputs, training=False):
    return tf.layers.batch_normalization(
        inputs, training=training, epsilon=self.bn_epsilon,
        gamma_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "scale"), dtype=tf.float32),
        beta_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "offset"), dtype=tf.float32),
        moving_mean_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "mean"), dtype=tf.float32),
        moving_variance_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(
            self.__get_weights(name, "variance"), dtype=tf.float32),
        name=name)

"""ResNet blocks
"""
def __conv_block(self, stage, block, inputs, filter_depths,
                 kernel_size=3, stride=2):
    filter_depth1, filter_depth2, filter_depth3 = filter_depths

    conv_name_base = "conv_stage{}_block{}_branch".format(stage, block)
    bn_name_base = "bn_stage{}_block{}_branch".format(stage, block)
    shortcut_name_post = "_stage{}_block{}_proj_shortcut" \
                         .format(stage, block)

    shortcut = self.__conv2d(
        name="conv{}".format(shortcut_name_post), stride=stride,
        inputs=inputs, filter_depth=filter_depth3, kernel_size=1,
        padding="same"
    )

    shortcut = self.__batch_norm("bn{}".format(shortcut_name_post),
                                 shortcut)

    x = self.__conv2d(
        name="{}2a".format(conv_name_base),
        inputs=inputs, filter_depth=filter_depth1, kernel_size=1,
        stride=stride, padding="same",
    )
    x = self.__batch_norm("{}2a".format(bn_name_base), x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.__conv2d(
        name="{}2b".format(conv_name_base),
        inputs=x, filter_depth=filter_depth2, kernel_size=kernel_size,
        padding="same", stride=1
    )
    x = self.__batch_norm("{}2b".format(bn_name_base), x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.__conv2d(
        name="{}2c".format(conv_name_base),
        inputs=x, filter_depth=filter_depth3, kernel_size=1,
        padding="same", stride=1
    )
    x = self.__batch_norm("{}2c".format(bn_name_base), x)

    x = tf.add(x, shortcut)

    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def __identity_block(self, stage, block, inputs,
                     filter_depths, kernel_size):
    filter_depth1, filter_depth2, filter_depth3 = filter_depths
    conv_name_base = "conv_stage{}_block{}_branch".format(stage, block)
    bn_name_base = "bn_stage{}_block{}_branch".format(stage, block)

    x = self.__conv2d(
        name="{}2a".format(conv_name_base),
        inputs=inputs, filter_depth=filter_depth1, kernel_size=1,
        stride=1, padding="same",
    )

    x = self.__batch_norm("{}2a".format(bn_name_base), x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.__conv2d(
        name="{}2b".format(conv_name_base),
        inputs=x, filter_depth=filter_depth2, kernel_size=kernel_size,
        padding="same", stride=1
    )
    x = self.__batch_norm("{}2b".format(bn_name_base), x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.__conv2d(
        name="{}2c".format(conv_name_base),
        inputs=x, filter_depth=filter_depth3, kernel_size=1,
        padding="same", stride=1
    )
    x = self.__batch_norm("{}2c".format(bn_name_base), x)

    x = tf.add(x, inputs)

    return tf.nn.relu(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save your trained model. When you get new images in your dataset, reload the saved model and continue training from that point onwards.

Refer Tensorflow docs: [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model)

Check out SO [how to save and restore a model in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)