# how to save and reload the tensorflow best model python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have created the following jupyter notebook.  I have used 200 epoches for the training purpose. But there was a power failure and the epoch it reached was 110. Now I need to restart it from zero. All my hardwork was wasted.

Have a look at the [Jupyter Notebook created by me](https://github.com/JafferWilson/test-tensorflow/blob/master/Currency_Market_Predictor_RNN.ipynb).

What should I do to save the train model and find out the best out of it? I want to restore the model saved even if there is any problem associated to power.

How to save and restore the model successfully? Currently I am going with 200 epoches but I soon think to move for 1000.

If possible then suggest me how I can move to Keras. I have heard it is simple to understand compare to Tensorflow.

Comment: You should use Pickle. Saving trained models (among other things) in exactly what it is used for.

Comment: Please can you help me with example or just telling me where I can do what to save and restore. PLease.

Comment: There is a tensorflow's own tutorial; [https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model] , have a look. try it and let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: [This question might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)