# How do I export an Estimator, tf.estimator.DNNClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

Hello guys this is my code, am still a beginner using tensorflow, this is my code
am trying to run a text classification DNN until now everything is fine.
I want to save my model and import it so i can use it to predict new values but I don't have any idea how to do it.

To give you a genral idea on  what am trying to do.
I have 2 folders (training & test)
each folder has (4 folders (classification categories))

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import seaborn as sns
import logging



print("Loading all files from directory ...")
# Load all files from a directory in a DataFrame.
def load_directory_data(directory):
  data = {}
  data["sentence"] = []
  data["tnemitnes"] = []
  print("getting in a loop")
  for file_path in os.listdir(directory):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(directory, file_path), "r") as f:
      print("directory : ",directory)
      print("file path : ",file_path)
      data["sentence"].append(f.read())
      data["tnemitnes"].append(re.match("(\d+)\.txt", file_path).group(1))
  return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print("merging all files in the training set ...")
# Merge all type of emails examples, add a polarity column and shuffle.
def load_dataset(directory):
  pos_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join("train/br"))
  neg_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join(directory, "train/mi"))
  dos_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join(directory, "train/Brouillons")) #dsd
  nos_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join(directory, "train/favoris")) #dsd
  pos_df["polarity"] = 3
  neg_df["polarity"] = 2
  dos_df["polarity"] = 1
  nos_df["polarity"] = 0
  return pd.concat([pos_df, neg_df, dos_df , nos_df]).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print("Getting the data from files ...")
# Download and process the dataset files.
def download_and_load_datasets():
  train_df = load_dataset(os.path.dirname("train"))
  test_df = load_dataset(os.path.dirname("test"))
  
  return train_df, test_df


print("configurring all logging output ...")
# Reduce logging output. ERROR
#logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)



print("Setting Up the data for the trainning ...")
train_df, test_df = download_and_load_datasets()
train_df.head()


print("Setting Up a Training input on the whole training set with no limit on training epochs ...")
# Training input on the whole training set with no limit on training epochs.
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(train_df, train_df["polarity"], num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

print("Setting Up a Prediction on the whole training set ...")
# Prediction on the whole training set.
predict_train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(train_df, train_df["polarity"], shuffle=False)

print("Setting Up a Prediction on the test set ...")
# Prediction on the test set.
predict_test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(test_df, test_df["polarity"], shuffle=False)


print("Removal of punctuation and splitting on spaces from the data ...")
#The module is responsible for preprocessing of sentences (e.g. removal of punctuation and splitting on spaces).
embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(key="sentence", module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")

print("Setting Up The Classifier ...")
#Estimator : For classification I did use a DNN Classifier
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[10, 20],
    feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
    n_classes=4,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))



print("Starting the Training ...")
# Training for 50 steps means 5000 training examples with the default
# batch size. This is roughly equivalent to 5 epochs since the training dataset
# contains less examples.
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=20);

print("the Training had ended...")

print("setting Up the results ...")
train_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_train_input_fn)
test_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_test_input_fn)


print("Showing the results ...")
print("Training set accuracy: {accuracy}".format(**train_eval_result))
print("Test set accuracy: {accuracy}".format(**test_eval_result))

#this is when am having trouble !!!  <====
tf.estimator.export(
    os.path.dirname("Model"),
    serving_input_fn,
    default_output_alternative_key=None,
    assets_extra=None,
    as_text=False,
    checkpoint_path=None,
    graph_rewrite_specs=(GraphRewriteSpec((tag_constants.SERVING,), ()),),
    strip_default_attrs=False
)
```

now after I have added the estimator export function it askes me to give ***serving_input_fn*** and to be honest I did find it hard to understand how to create one.

if there is an easier way it would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can esily get a serving_input_fn with `tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn))

In your case do something like:

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        [embedded_text_feature_column])
```

If you expect to pass tensors directly there's also `build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn` in the same package.

Comment: Thank you. this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do is add ***model_dir= os.getcwd()+'\Model'*** to the estimator

```html
model_dir= os.getcwd()+'\Model'
```

this is the new Code , I have created a new Folder and named it model.

```html
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[10, 20],
    feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
    n_classes=4,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003),
    model_dir= os.getcwd()+'\Model')
```

Answer (score 1):

You might read this before.
[Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)

A serving_input_receiver_fn should be defined.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn

This document introduce a valuable method to build the serving_input_receiver_fn.

Here is the example:

```
# first you should prepare feature_spec. it include the speciation of your feature columns. 

feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(my_feature_columns)
print feature_spec
serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)

export_model = classifier.export_savedmodel('./iris/', serving_input_receiver_fn)
```