# How to use tensorflow model in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am following this blog to train a text prediction model using RNN.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent

I am able to run the code and save the model to a specific directory.

```
python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=$HOME/simple-examples/data/ --model=small
```

But in the blog, its not mentioned that, how to load and this model. 
Also, the saved model does not contain any .pb extension.

can anybody help to understand this.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model

Comment: You may try this method: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/loader/load