# What's the difference between predictions and export_outputs of tensorflow custom estimator, and how to use them?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want to save my tensorflow model and restore it later for predicting, and I use the estimator's `export_savedmodel` to save the model.

As to docs, I use `serving_input_receiver_fn` to specify the input. I also want to use `export_outputs` to specify the output, but I am not understanding the difference between predictions and export_outputs?

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    export_outputs = {
        'predict_output': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput({
            'class_ids': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
            'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits),
            'logits': logits
        })
    }
    predictions = {
        'class': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
        'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits),
        'logits': logits,
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions, export_outputs=export_outputs)
```

Another problem is how to use the saved pb model to predict in a session?

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    model_path = 'model/1535016490'
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], model_path)
    inputs = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_example:0')
    # how to get the output tensor?
    # outputs = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name()
    res = sess.run([outputs], feed_dict={inputs: examples})
```

I can use the `tensorflow.contrib.predictor` to get some result, but I want an universal method for our team will restore the model with C++. So I think get tensors and run them in a session maybe the method I want?

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(
    export_dir='model/1535012949',
    signature_def_key='predict_output',
    tags=tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING
)

predictions = predict_fn({'examples': examples})
```

Very thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I'm not 100% certain, but I believe that predictions are used when you call estimator.predict(...) within a tf.session() whereas the export_outputs is used during serving. By that, I mean, if you have a docker tensorflow/serving or some other server running and loaded with a saved model, and you query it with an input, the response will be based on your export_outputs definition.

I'm sorry I don't know a good answer to your second question. There are so many differing ways to save a tensorflow model at this point that it's hard to tell. I would say to look at the official documentation for [save and restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) and find the suggested restore method based on how you save your model and whether or not you use estimators.

Also, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model) on the frontpage of #tensorflow might be useful.

Good luck~~

Answer (score 0):

For those who landed here looking for information about export_outputs and predictions,make sure to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53414168/4936825) as well.