# TensorFlow ExportOutputs, PredictOuput, and specifying signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

## Context

I have a [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub) with a very simple demo [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) for the purpose of learning / understanding the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) API with the goal of making a convention for a plug-and-play model with useful bells and whistles of the trade in tack (e.g. early stopping if the validation set stops improving, exporting the model, etc).

Each of the three [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) modes (`TRAIN`, `EVAL`, and `PREDICT`) return an [`EstimatorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec).

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec):

```
__new__(
    cls,
    mode,
    predictions=None,          # required by PREDICT
    loss=None,                 # required by TRAIN and EVAL
    train_op=None,             # required by TRAIN
    eval_metric_ops=None,
    export_outputs=None,
    training_chief_hooks=None,
    training_hooks=None,
    scaffold=None,
    evaluation_hooks=None,
    prediction_hooks=None.     
)
```

Of these named arguments I would like to bring attention to `predictions` and `export_outputs`, which are described in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) as:

> - **`predictions`**: Predictions Tensor or dict of Tensor.
> - **`export_outputs`**: Describes the output signatures to be exported to `SavedModel` and used during serving. A dict `{name: output}` where:
>
>   - `name`: An arbitrary name for this output.
>   - `output`: an [`ExportOutput`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/ExportOutput) object such as `ClassificationOutput`, `RegressionOutput`, or [`PredictOutput`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/PredictOutput). Single-headed models only need to specify one entry in this dictionary. Multi-headed models should specify one entry for each head, one of which must be named using `signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY`. If no entry is provided, a default `PredictOutput` mapping to predictions will be created.

Thus it should be clear why I bring up `export_outputs`; namely, as one would most likely like to use the model they trained in the future (by loading it from a `SavedModel`).

To make this question a bit more accessible / add some clarity:

- "single-headed" models are the most common model one encounters where the `input_fn` `features` are transformed to a singular (batched) `output`
- "multi-headed" models are models where there is more than one output

e.g. this multi-headed model's `input_fn` (in accordance with the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) api) returns a tuple `(features, labels)` i.e. this model has two heads).

```
def input_fn():
  features = ...
  labels1 = ...
  labels2 = ...
  return features, {'head1': labels1, 'head2': labels2}
```

How one specifies the `signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY` is the core of this question. Namely, how does one specify it? (e.g. should it be a dict `{signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: head}`)

Right, so in the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub) you see that our model's `export_outputs` is actually defined in a multi-head manner (although it shouldn't be):

From `estimator functions > model_fn` of the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub):

```
def model_fn(...):

    # ...

    # send the features through the graph
    MODEL = build_fn(MODEL)

    # prediction
    MODEL['predictions'] = {'labels': MODEL['net_logits']} # <--- net_logits added in the build_fn

    MODEL['export_outputs'] = {
        k: tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(v) for k, v in MODEL['predictions'].items()
    }

    # ...
```

in this particular instance, if we expand the dictionary comprehension, we have the functional equivalent of:

```
MODEL['export_outputs'] = {
    'labels': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(MODEL['net_logits'])
}
```

It works in this instance as our dictionary has one key and hence one [`PredictOutput`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/PredictOutput), where in the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub) our `model_fn` has only a single head and would be more properly formatted as:

```
MODEL['export_outputs'] = {
    'predictions': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(MODEL['predictions'])
}
```

as it states in [`PredictOutput`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/PredictOutput):

```
__init__(outputs)
```

where

- `outputs`: A Tensor or a dict of string to Tensor representing the predictions.

## Question

Thus my question is as follows:

1. if [`PredictOutput`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/PredictOutput) can be a dictionary, when / why would one want multiple [`PredictOutput`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/PredictOutput)s as their `export_outputs` for the [`EstimatorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec)?
2. If one has a multi-headed model, (say with multiple [`PredictOutput`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/PredictOutput)s) how does one actually specify the `signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY`
3. what is the point of `predictions` in the [`EstimatorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) when it is also "required" (for anyone who cares about using `SavedModel`s) in `export_outputs`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your detailed question; you have clearly dug deep here.

1. There are also classes for RegressionOutput and ClassificationOutput which cannot be dictionaries. The use of an export_outputs dict allows for generalizations over those use cases.
2. The head you want to be served by default from the saved model should take the default signature key. For example:

```
export_outputs = {
  signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
    PredictOutput(outputs={'some_output_1': output_1}),
  'head-2': PredictOutput(outputs={'some_output_2': output_2}),
  'head-3': PredictOutput(outputs={'some_output_3': output_3})
}
```

3. Reason 1: Many people use the default export_outputs (which is in turn the value of predictions), or don't export to saved model. Reason 2: History. Predictions came first, and over time more and more features were added. These features required flexibility and extra info, and were therefore independently packed into the EstimatorSpec.