# KeyError u'ImageProjectiveTransform' when loading Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a ConvNet on *MNIST*, and saved the model using *simple_save*.

When loading the saved model, using `tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tag_constants.SERVING],'/save_folder')`

I get this error `KeyError: u'ImageProjectiveTransform`

Code for saving my ConvNet model

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
with graph.as_default():
  input_dict = {"x":x,"y":y,"keep_prob":keep_prob,"aug_img":aug_img}
  output_dict = {"logits":fc3}
  tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess,'/sample_data/',input_dict,output_dict)
```

I used `tf.contrib.image.rotate` as a augmentation technique, but didn't add that to any of the dicts while saving the model.

Is the error arising due to that? or is there any other issue?