# using a trained cnn for a test data

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm training a CNN in Tensorflow and I save it with the code:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

end of each Epoch I save it using this, 
`saver.save(sess,Save_Dir)`.

After my CNN has been trained, I want to use it on a test data. I wonder, How I can restore my Trained CNN and How I can see How my trained CNN works on test data that I have. I've searched a lot in this regard, but I didn't find something that I can Learn about the process. Moreover, I do not have any sense about the 4 types of files that the saver generate. (.meta,....).
Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> restore my Trained CNN

To load your model, you do `saver.restore(session, load_path)` which should load the graph back into the session.

> How I can see How my trained CNN works on test data that I have

You can use `tf.metrics` or define your own custom metric

> Moreover, I do not have any sense about the 4 types of files that the saver generate. (.meta,....). Thank You.

I found [Tensorflow: The confusing Parts 2](https://jacobbuckman.com/post/tensorflow-the-confusing-parts-2/) to be extremely useful.