# How to save and restore trained LSTM model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/stuarteiffert/RNN-for-Human-Activity-Recognition-using-2D-Pose-Input).
I like to restore back LSTM model to run test data.
`pred` is LSTM model and its function is

```
def LSTM_RNN(_X, _weights, _biases):
    # model architecture based on "guillaume-chevalier" and "aymericdamien" under the MIT license.

    _X = tf.transpose(_X, [1, 0, 2])  # permute n_steps and batch_size
    _X = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, n_input])   
    # Rectifies Linear Unit activation function used
    _X = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden'])
    # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
    _X = tf.split(_X, n_steps, 0) 

    # Define two stacked LSTM cells (two recurrent layers deep) with tensorflow
    lstm_cell_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cell_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_1, lstm_cell_2], state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cells, _X, dtype=tf.float32)

    # A single output is produced, in style of "many to one" classifier, refer to http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ for details
    lstm_last_output = outputs[-1]

    # Linear activation
    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
```

How to restore back `pred` model?

The code is as follow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf  # Version 1.0.0 (some previous versions are used in past commits)
from sklearn import metrics
import random
from random import randint
import time
import os
# Useful Constants

# Output classes to learn how to classify
LABELS = [    
    "JUMPING",
    "JUMPING_JACKS",
    "BOXING",
    "WAVING_2HANDS",
    "WAVING_1HAND",
    "CLAPPING_HANDS"

] 
DATASET_PATH = "data/HAR_pose_activities/database/"

X_train_path = DATASET_PATH + "X_train.txt"
X_test_path = DATASET_PATH + "X_test.txt"

y_train_path = DATASET_PATH + "Y_train.txt"
y_test_path = DATASET_PATH + "Y_test.txt"

n_steps = 32 # 32 timesteps per series
# Load the networks inputs

def load_X(X_path):
    file = open(X_path, 'r')
    X_ = np.array(
        [elem for elem in [
            row.split(',') for row in file
        ]], 
        dtype=np.float32
    )
    file.close()
    blocks = int(len(X_) / n_steps)

    X_ = np.array(np.split(X_,blocks))

    return X_ 

# Load the networks outputs

def load_y(y_path):
    file = open(y_path, 'r')
    y_ = np.array(
        [elem for elem in [
            row.replace('  ', ' ').strip().split(' ') for row in file
        ]], 
        dtype=np.int32
    )
    file.close()

    # for 0-based indexing 
    return y_ - 1

X_train = load_X(X_train_path)
X_test = load_X(X_test_path)
#print X_test

y_train = load_y(y_train_path)
y_test = load_y(y_test_path)
# proof that it actually works for the skeptical: replace labelled classes with random classes to train on
#for i in range(len(y_train)):
#    y_train[i] = randint(0, 5)
# Input Data 

training_data_count = len(X_train)  # 4519 training series (with 50% overlap between each serie)
test_data_count = len(X_test)  # 1197 test series
n_input = len(X_train[0][0])  # num input parameters per timestep

n_hidden = 34 # Hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 6 

#updated for learning-rate decay
# calculated as: decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate * decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
decaying_learning_rate = True
learning_rate = 0.0025 #used if decaying_learning_rate set to False
init_learning_rate = 0.005
decay_rate = 0.96 #the base of the exponential in the decay
decay_steps = 100000 #used in decay every 60000 steps with a base of 0.96

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
lambda_loss_amount = 0.0015

training_iters = training_data_count *300  # Loop 300 times on the dataset, ie 300 epochs
batch_size = 512
display_iter = batch_size*8  # To show test set accuracy during training

print("(X shape, y shape, every X's mean, every X's standard deviation)")
print(X_train.shape, y_test.shape, np.mean(X_test), np.std(X_test))
print("\nThe dataset has not been preprocessed, is not normalised etc")

#Utility functions for training:
def LSTM_RNN(_X, _weights, _biases):
    # model architecture based on "guillaume-chevalier" and "aymericdamien" under the MIT license.

    _X = tf.transpose(_X, [1, 0, 2])  # permute n_steps and batch_size
    _X = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, n_input])   
    # Rectifies Linear Unit activation function used
    _X = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden'])
    # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
    _X = tf.split(_X, n_steps, 0) 

    # Define two stacked LSTM cells (two recurrent layers deep) with tensorflow
    lstm_cell_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cell_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_1, lstm_cell_2], state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cells, _X, dtype=tf.float32)

    # A single output is produced, in style of "many to one" classifier, refer to http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ for details
    lstm_last_output = outputs[-1]

    # Linear activation
    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']


def extract_batch_size(_train, _labels, _unsampled, batch_size):
    # Fetch a "batch_size" amount of data and labels from "(X|y)_train" data. 
    # Elements of each batch are chosen randomly, without replacement, from X_train with corresponding label from Y_train
    # unsampled_indices keeps track of sampled data ensuring non-replacement. Resets when remaining datapoints < batch_size    

    shape = list(_train.shape)
    shape[0] = batch_size
    batch_s = np.empty(shape)
    batch_labels = np.empty((batch_size,1)) 

    for i in range(batch_size):
        # Loop index
        # index = random sample from _unsampled (indices)
        index = random.choice(_unsampled)
        batch_s[i] = _train[index] 
        batch_labels[i] = _labels[index]
        _unsampled.remove(index)


    return batch_s, batch_labels, _unsampled


def one_hot(y_):
    # One hot encoding of the network outputs
    # e.g.: [[5], [0], [3]] --> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

    y_ = y_.reshape(len(y_))
    n_values = int(np.max(y_)) + 1
    return np.eye(n_values)[np.array(y_, dtype=np.int32)]  # Returns FLOATS

# Graph input/output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Graph weights
weights = {
'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden])), # Hidden layer weights
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes], mean=1.0))
}
biases = {
'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

pred = LSTM_RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Loss, optimizer and evaluation
l2 = lambda_loss_amount * sum(
tf.nn.l2_loss(tf_var) for tf_var in tf.trainable_variables()
) # L2 loss prevents this overkill neural network to overfit the data
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=pred)) + l2 # Softmax loss
if decaying_learning_rate:
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(init_learning_rate, global_step*batch_size, decay_steps, decay_rate, staircase=True)


#decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate * decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps) #exponentially decayed learning rate
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost,global_step=global_step) # Adam Optimizer

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

#Train the network:
test_losses = []
test_accuracies = []
train_losses = []
train_accuracies = []
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(init)

# Perform Training steps with "batch_size" amount of data at each loop. 
# Elements of each batch are chosen randomly, without replacement, from X_train, 
# restarting when remaining datapoints < batch_size
step = 1
time_start = time.time()
unsampled_indices = range(0,len(X_train))
while step * batch_size <= training_iters:
    #print (sess.run(learning_rate)) #decaying learning rate
    #print (sess.run(global_step)) # global number of iterations
    if len(unsampled_indices) < batch_size:
        unsampled_indices = range(0,len(X_train)) 
    batch_xs, raw_labels, unsampled_indicies = extract_batch_size(X_train, y_train, unsampled_indices, batch_size)
    batch_ys = one_hot(raw_labels)
    # check that encoded output is same length as num_classes, if not, pad it 
    if len(batch_ys[0]) < n_classes:
        temp_ys = np.zeros((batch_size, n_classes))
        temp_ys[:batch_ys.shape[0],:batch_ys.shape[1]] = batch_ys
        batch_ys = temp_ys



    # Fit training using batch data
    _, loss, acc = sess.run(
        [optimizer, cost, accuracy],
        feed_dict={
            x: batch_xs, 
            y: batch_ys
        }
    )
    train_losses.append(loss)
    train_accuracies.append(acc)

    # Evaluate network only at some steps for faster training: 
    if (step*batch_size % display_iter == 0) or (step == 1) or (step * batch_size > training_iters):

        # To not spam console, show training accuracy/loss in this "if"
        print("Iter #" + str(step*batch_size) + \
              ":  Learning rate = " + "{:.6f}".format(sess.run(learning_rate)) + \
              ":   Batch Loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + \
              ", Accuracy = {}".format(acc))

        # Evaluation on the test set (no learning made here - just evaluation for diagnosis)
        loss, acc = sess.run(
            [cost, accuracy], 
            feed_dict={
                x: X_test,
                y: one_hot(y_test)
            }
        )
        test_losses.append(loss)
        test_accuracies.append(acc)
        print("PERFORMANCE ON TEST SET:             " + \
              "Batch Loss = {}".format(loss) + \
              ", Accuracy = {}".format(acc))

    step += 1

print("Optimization Finished!")
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/home/coie/venv/TFCodes/HumanActivityRecognition/model.ckpt")
print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

The code has pred = LSTM_RNN(x, weights, biases) prediction model.
From the saved model.ckpt.

I can restore as

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/coie/venv/TFCodes/HumanActivityRecognition/model.ckpt.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, '/home/coie/venv/TFCodes/HumanActivityRecognition/model.ckpt')
  print("Model restored.")
```

My query is how can I restore the pred model so that I can test with test data array as

```
one_hot_predictions, accuracy, final_loss = sess.run(
    [pred, accuracy, cost],
    feed_dict={
        x: X_test,
        y: one_hot(y_test)
    }
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)

Comment: Prefer Checkpoint over Saver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577920/1462770

Comment: I can restore sess. From sess, how to get our pred. When I run like `sess.run()`. I have error as `name 'pred' is not defined`. I thought `pred` is saved with `sess`