# What do I need to save and restore for LSTM model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am new to Tensorflow and I am working for training with LSTM-RNN in Tensorflow.
I need to save the model so that I can restore and run with Test data again.
I am not sure what to save.

I need to save `sess` or I need to save `pred`
When I save `sess`, restore and test the Test data as

```
one_hot_predictions, accuracy, final_loss = sess.run(
    [pred, accuracy, cost],
    feed_dict={
        x: X_test,
        y: one_hot(y_test)      

 }
)
```

Then the error is `unknown for pred`.
Since I am new to Tensorflow, I am not sure what to save and what to restore to test with new data?

```
X_train = load_X(X_train_path)
X_test = load_X(X_test_path)


y_train = load_y(y_train_path)
y_test = load_y(y_test_path)
# proof that it actually works for the skeptical: replace labelled classes with random classes to train on
#for i in range(len(y_train)):
#    y_train[i] = randint(0, 5)
# Input Data 

training_data_count = len(X_train)  # 4519 training series (with 50% overlap between each serie)
test_data_count = len(X_test)  # 1197 test series
n_input = len(X_train[0][0])  # num input parameters per timestep

n_hidden = 34 # Hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 6 

#updated for learning-rate decay
# calculated as: decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate * decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
decaying_learning_rate = True
learning_rate = 0.0025 #used if decaying_learning_rate set to False
init_learning_rate = 0.005
decay_rate = 0.96 #the base of the exponential in the decay
decay_steps = 100000 #used in decay every 60000 steps with a base of 0.96

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
lambda_loss_amount = 0.0015

training_iters = training_data_count *300  # Loop 300 times on the dataset, ie 300 epochs
batch_size = 512
display_iter = batch_size*8  # To show test set accuracy during training


#Utility functions for training:
def LSTM_RNN(_X, _weights, _biases):
    # model architecture based on "guillaume-chevalier" and "aymericdamien" under the MIT license.

    _X = tf.transpose(_X, [1, 0, 2])  # permute n_steps and batch_size
    _X = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, n_input])   
    # Rectifies Linear Unit activation function used
    _X = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden'])
    # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
    _X = tf.split(_X, n_steps, 0) 

    # Define two stacked LSTM cells (two recurrent layers deep) with tensorflow
    lstm_cell_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cell_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_1, lstm_cell_2], state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cells, _X, dtype=tf.float32)

    # A single output is produced, in style of "many to one" classifier, refer to http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ for details
    lstm_last_output = outputs[-1]

    # Linear activation
    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']


def extract_batch_size(_train, _labels, _unsampled, batch_size):
    # Fetch a "batch_size" amount of data and labels from "(X|y)_train" data. 
    # Elements of each batch are chosen randomly, without replacement, from X_train with corresponding label from Y_train
    # unsampled_indices keeps track of sampled data ensuring non-replacement. Resets when remaining datapoints < batch_size    

    shape = list(_train.shape)
    shape[0] = batch_size
    batch_s = np.empty(shape)
    batch_labels = np.empty((batch_size,1)) 

    for i in range(batch_size):
        # Loop index
        # index = random sample from _unsampled (indices)
        index = random.choice(_unsampled)
        batch_s[i] = _train[index] 
        batch_labels[i] = _labels[index]
        _unsampled.remove(index)


    return batch_s, batch_labels, _unsampled


def one_hot(y_):
    # One hot encoding of the network outputs
    # e.g.: [[5], [0], [3]] --> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

    y_ = y_.reshape(len(y_))
    n_values = int(np.max(y_)) + 1
    return np.eye(n_values)[np.array(y_, dtype=np.int32)]  # Returns FLOATS

# Graph input/output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Graph weights
weights = {
'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden])), # Hidden layer weights
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes], mean=1.0))
}
biases = {
'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

pred = LSTM_RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Loss, optimizer and evaluation
l2 = lambda_loss_amount * sum(
tf.nn.l2_loss(tf_var) for tf_var in tf.trainable_variables()
) # L2 loss prevents this overkill neural network to overfit the data
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=pred)) + l2 # Softmax loss
if decaying_learning_rate:
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(init_learning_rate, global_step*batch_size, decay_steps, decay_rate, staircase=True)


#decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate * decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps) #exponentially decayed learning rate
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost,global_step=global_step) # Adam Optimizer

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

#Train the network:
test_losses = []
test_accuracies = []
train_losses = []
train_accuracies = []
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(init)

# Perform Training steps with "batch_size" amount of data at each loop. 
# Elements of each batch are chosen randomly, without replacement, from X_train, 
# restarting when remaining datapoints < batch_size
step = 1
time_start = time.time()
unsampled_indices = range(0,len(X_train))
while step * batch_size <= training_iters:
    #print (sess.run(learning_rate)) #decaying learning rate
    #print (sess.run(global_step)) # global number of iterations
    if len(unsampled_indices) < batch_size:
        unsampled_indices = range(0,len(X_train)) 
    batch_xs, raw_labels, unsampled_indicies = extract_batch_size(X_train, y_train, unsampled_indices, batch_size)
    batch_ys = one_hot(raw_labels)
    # check that encoded output is same length as num_classes, if not, pad it 
    if len(batch_ys[0]) < n_classes:
        temp_ys = np.zeros((batch_size, n_classes))
        temp_ys[:batch_ys.shape[0],:batch_ys.shape[1]] = batch_ys
        batch_ys = temp_ys



    # Fit training using batch data
    _, loss, acc = sess.run(
        [optimizer, cost, accuracy],
        feed_dict={
            x: batch_xs, 
            y: batch_ys
        }
    )
    train_losses.append(loss)
    train_accuracies.append(acc)

    # Evaluate network only at some steps for faster training: 
    if (step*batch_size % display_iter == 0) or (step == 1) or (step * batch_size > training_iters):

        # To not spam console, show training accuracy/loss in this "if"
        print("Iter #" + str(step*batch_size) + \
              ":  Learning rate = " + "{:.6f}".format(sess.run(learning_rate)) + \
              ":   Batch Loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + \
              ", Accuracy = {}".format(acc))

        # Evaluation on the test set (no learning made here - just evaluation for diagnosis)
        loss, acc = sess.run(
            [cost, accuracy], 
            feed_dict={
                x: X_test,
                y: one_hot(y_test)
            }
        )
        test_losses.append(loss)
        test_accuracies.append(acc)
        print("PERFORMANCE ON TEST SET:             " + \
              "Batch Loss = {}".format(loss) + \
              ", Accuracy = {}".format(acc))

    step += 1

print("Optimization Finished!")
```

EDIT:

I can save the model as

print("Optimization Finished!")
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/home/test/venv/TFCodes/HumanActivityRecognition/model.ckpt")

Then I tried to restore and ok, I can restore. But I don't know how to test with test data.
My restore code is

```
X_test = load_X(X_test_path)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/nyan/venv/TFCodes/HumanActivityRecognition/model.ckpt.meta')
  saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
  print("Model restored.")

  all_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
  for i in range(len(all_vars)):
        name = all_vars[i].name
        values = sess.run(name)
        print('name', name)
        #print('value', values)
        print('shape',values.shape)
  result = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: X_test})
  print("loss:", l, "prediction:", result, "true Y:", y_data)

  # print char using dic
  result_str = [idx2char[c] for c in np.squeeze(res

ult)]
  print("\tPrediction str:", ''.join(result_str))
```

The output is

```
Model restored.
('name', u'Variable_1:0')
('shape', (36, 34))
('name', u'Variable_2:0')
('shape', (34, 6))
('name', u'Variable_3:0')
('shape', (34,))
('name', u'Variable_4:0')
('shape', (6,))
('name', u'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel:0')
('shape', (68, 136))
('name', u'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias:0')
('shape', (136,))
('name', u'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel:0')
('shape', (68, 136))
('name', u'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/bias:0')
('shape', (136,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restore.py", line 74, in <module>
    result = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: X_test})
NameError: name 'prediction' is not defined
```

How to test the model restored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: how to save/restore a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model)

Answer (score 0):

What I find the easiest is the tf.saved_model.simple_save() function. It saves the computation graph you use, the weights, the input and the output in a .pb model and the weight variables.
You can later restore this model or even put it on ml-engine or use tf serving.

An example code snippit with a keras model and applied on YOLO:

```
    inputs =    {"image_bytes": model.input,
                    "shape": image_shape}

    outputs = {"boxes": boxes,
               "scores": scores,
               "classes": classes}

    tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, "saved_model/", inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Then to test with restore model, say my test data is X_test, how can I test?

Comment: I can save and restore. How to test with restored model?

Comment: After restoring your model, you should be able to just use sess.run as you would do otherwise. Some more info on how to restore your model is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model