# Convert output of retrain.py to tensorflow.js

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflow-hub, tensorflowjs-converter

The script retrain.py described in [How to Retrain an Image Classifier for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) was run as

```
python retrain.py --tfhub_module https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/2 --image_dir /tmp/test
```

and produced the output file `/tmp/output_graph.pb`. [Converting this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/blob/master/docs/supported_ops.md) with

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model /tmp/output_graph.pb /tmp/model
```

failed with

> IOError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /tmp/output_graph.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

If the file `output_graph.pb` is renamed to `saved_model.pb` ([by @edkeveked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830563/1587329)), the error changes to

> RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags 'serve' could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`

`saved_model_cli show --dir .` reports an empty tag set.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: The error says it all. The file is not found

Comment: @edkeveked: the file `/tmp/output_graph.pb` exists along with `output_labels.txt`. Is this a different format?

Comment: Have you solved it? I ran into the same problem using the tfjs sample [mobilenet V2,](https://storage.googleapis.com/mobilenet_v2/checkpoints/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224.tgz)

Comment: @季谢尔: No. The alternative failed as well. Even a bounty on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849309/retrain-image-detection-with-mobilenet?noredirect=1&lq=1 yielded no result. See the issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28365

Comment: @季谢尔: see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56084489/1587329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by @Ping Yu in [Retrain image detection with MobileNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849309), you can use

```
python retrain.py --tfhub_module https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/2 \
    --image_dir /tmp/flower_photos --saved_model_dir /tmp/saved_retrained_model
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_format=tfjs_graph_model \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    /tmp/saved_retrained_model/ /tmp/converted_model/
```

This saves the model using the saved model format.

Answer (score 2):

The input path is the path of the folder and not of the file. Consider the following:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model /tmp /tmp/model
```

Comment: After changing to the directory and renaming the `.pb` file, a different error occurs. See the edit. Still a step in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Though I can't tell exactly why you're having the current error, I could suggest to add other flags `--output_node_names="final_result"`, `--saved_model_tags=serve` to tfjs-converter command.

Comment: both together yielded "*TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: unrecognized arguments: --output_node_names=final_result*", skipping that resulted in the same "*RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags 'serve' could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`*"