# keras.models.load_model fails with 'tags' = train

Tags: python, c, tensorflow, keras

I am exploring the c API for tensorflow 2.0.

Problem:
When loading model into python,weights are not restored and thus model seems to be untrained.

Workflow:
I am using TF 2.0 C api to handle the training of my model.
The general setup I follow is:

**1. Define model in python using TF keras api.**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(128,
                                             input_shape=(784,),
                                             activation='relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
                        ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy'])

keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model,"keras_model")
```

I am using keras.experimental.export_saved_model() because I need the "signature_def['train']" which is not saved when using keras.Model.save().

**2. Train model in C using TF 2.0 C api**
Saved model is then loaded into my C program via:

```c
TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel()
```

Subsequently it is trained and checkpoints are saved with:

```c
TF_SessionRun()
```

Saving the model creates new checkpoints files ("checkpoint.index" and "checkpoint.data-00000-of-00001") in the "variables" folder of where my model is stored.

**3. PROBLEM Reload model in python**
After training I reload my model in python. This is where I find out that the loaded model has wights corresponding to the untrained model. I know this because predictions are giberish when my trained model in C was predicting accurately.
I load my model via:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model("keras_model")
```

Again, I am using keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model() because when I use keras.models.load_model() I get the following ValueError:

```py
ValueError: Importing a SavedModel with tf.saved_model.load requires a 'tags=' argument if there is more than one MetaGraph. Got 'tags=None', but there are 3 MetaGraphs in the SavedModel with tag sets [['train'], ['eval'], ['serve']]. Pass a 'tags=' argument to load this SavedModel.
```

If I pass a "tags=serve" argument to keras.model.load_model() I get the following TypeError:

```py
TypeError: load_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tags'
```

Trying to load the saved checkpoints file into my model via keras.Model.load_weights() results in an OSErro due to the file format:

```py
h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

**Questions**
What is the correct way to load a trained model via it's checkpoints file?

How do I save a model **not** using keras.experimental.export_saved_model and still be able to access the signature_def['train']?