# How to load and save a model in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

In tensorflow 2.0, once the model is trained, how do we save the model to prevent retraining it from the beginning?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770331/349130 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have trained your model, to **save** it you can use the following code:

```
model.save('model.h5')
```

`model` is the name of my model, 'model.h5' will be the name of the file containing the trained model where, '.h5' is the extension.

An H5 file is a data file saved in the Hierarchical Data Format (HDF). It contains multidimensional arrays of scientific data.

Now, to **load** this saved model, you can use the following code:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

Have a look at this example for a better understanding:

https://github.com/TheArhaam/Python-ML-Basics/blob/master/demo6.py