# Problem when saving a machine learning keras model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I follow this tutorial on keras
https://keras.io/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert/

I wanted to save the model with this command

```
model.save("saved_model/my_model")
```

I got this warnings when i saved the model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8SIN.png)

Then when i want to load the model to use it with this command

```
 tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')
```

I got this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CGyW.png)

Is this the good way to save the model ?

Answer (score 0):

your first structure is inside a dict. You must extract the item from the dict to be able to get rid of your error. Try checking [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) out.

Comment: But where should I do that ?  Because I just created a model and I want to save it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759623/tensorflow-how-to-save-restore-a-model?rq=1  This gives a nice explanation on how to create and save a model