# Save Tensorflow model to tf.keras model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I used the tensorflow2 object detection API. I received a `saved_model.pb` which is a TensorFlow graph and not a `tf.keras model`. So it can be loaded with `tf.saved_model.load()` but not with `tf.keras.load_model()`. The model is saved via the `tf.saved_model.save()` in the [export_lib_v2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/exporter_lib_v2.py) of the object detection API in line 271.

I tried to build the model from the config file and load the checkpoints, to then save it as a tf.keras model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
import os
 
def save_in_tfkeras(save_filepath,label_map_path, config_file_path, checkpoint_path):
    configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(config_file_path)
    model_config = configs['model']
    detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)
 
    # Restore checkpoint
    ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
    ckpt.restore(checkpoint_path).expect_partial()
    detection_model.built(input_shape=(320,320))

    tf.keras.models.save_model(detection_model, save_filepath)
    print('modelsaved as tf.keras in ' + save_filepath)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    PATH_TO_LABELMAP = './models/face_model/face_label.pbtxt'
    PATH_TO_CONFIG = './models/face_model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config'
    PATH_TO_CHECKPOINT = './models/face_model/v2_model_50k/ckpt-51'    
    
    save_filepath='./Kmodels/mobileNet_V2'
    if not os.path.exists(save_filepath):
        os.makedirs(save_filepath)
    save_in_tfkeras(save_filepath,PATH_TO_LABELMAP,PATH_TO_CONFIG,PATH_TO_CHECKPOINT)
```

However, this does not seem to work. There are  errors which origin, in my opinion, in mixing the tf and tf.keras model. The last error message:

> ValueError: Weights for model
> ssd_mobile_net_v2fpn_keras_feature_extractor_1 have not yet been
> created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs
> or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.

The model was saved with TensorFlow loaded as `tensorflow.compat.v2`

**Question: Is there a way to build the model, load the checkpoint weights and then save as tf.keras model?**

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions per post. There is nothing wrong in opening two questions for two different issues.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50852627/6596684

Comment: @desertnaut. Sorry, I will delete the second question.

Comment: @SiriPadNewton Thanks for the link